# Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, count, element

In Javascript, I'm trying to take an initial array of number values and count the elements inside it. Ideally, the result would be two new arrays, the first specifying each unique element, and the second containing the number of times each element occurs. However, I'm open to suggestions on the format of the output.

For example, if the initial array was:

```
5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4
```

Then two new arrays would be created. The first would contain the name of each unique element:

```
5, 2, 9, 4
```

The second would contain the number of times that element occurred in the initial array:

```
3, 5, 1, 1
```

Because the number 5 occurs three times in the initial array, the number 2 occurs five times and 9 and 4 both appear once.

I've searched a lot for a solution, but nothing seems to work, and everything I've tried myself has wound up being ridiculously complex. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

Comment: If all you needed was to see if a value appears only once (instead of two or more times), you could use `if (arr.indexOf(value) == arr.lastIndexOf(value))`

Comment: We can use `ramda.js` to achieve this the easy way. 
```const ary = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
R.countBy(r=> r)(ary)```

Comment: `arr.filter(x => x===5).length` would return `3` to indicate that there are '3' fives in the array.

Comment: Let us assume My response is array of object

Answer (score 117, accepted):

```js
const arr = [2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 9];

function foo (array) {
  let a = [],
    b = [],
    arr = [...array], // clone array so we don't change the original when using .sort()
    prev;

  arr.sort();
  for (let element of arr) {
    if (element !== prev) {
      a.push(element);
      b.push(1);
    }
    else ++b[b.length - 1];
    prev = element;
  }

  return [a, b];
}

const result = foo(arr);
console.log('[' + result[0] + ']','[' + result[1] + ']')
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: has side-effect of sorting the array (side effects are bad), also sorting is `O(N log(N))` and the elegance gain isn't worth it

Comment: In absence of a nice high-level primitive from a third-party library, I would normally implement this like the `reduce` answer. I was about to submit such an answer before I saw it already existed. Nevertheless the `counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1 : 1` answer also works (equivalent to the `if(!result[a[i]])result[a[i]]=0` answer, which is more elegant but less easy to read); this answers can be modified to use a "nicer" version of the for loop, perhaps a third-party for-loop, but I sort of ignored that since the standard index-based for-loops are sadly the default.

Comment: For small arrays sorting it in-place can be faster than creating an associative array.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas I added a disclaimer for `Array.sort`, because missing this fact has tripped me up in real code. (It's easy to naively treat it as if it makes a copy, since it returns the sorted array.)

Comment: Agree with @ninjagecko. `dictionary` would be better. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66002712/9071943) is my answer to another approach.

Answer (score 344):

You can use an object to hold the results:

```js
const arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
const counts = {};

for (const num of arr) {
  counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num] + 1 : 1;
}

console.log(counts);
console.log(counts[5], counts[2], counts[9], counts[4]);
```

So, now your `counts` object can tell you what the count is for a particular number:

```
console.log(counts[5]); // logs '3'
```

If you want to get an array of members, just use the `keys()` functions

```
keys(counts); // returns ["5", "2", "9", "4"]
```

Comment: It should be pointed out, that `Object.keys()` function is only supported in IE9+, FF4+, SF5+, CH6+ but Opera doesn't support it. I think the biggest show stopper here is **IE9+**.

Comment: Similarly, I also like `counts[num] = (counts[num] || 0) + 1`. That way you only have to write `counts[num]` twice instead of three times on that one line there.

Comment: This is a nice answer. This is easily abstracted into a function that accepts an array and returns a 'counts' object.

Comment: This is true for the specific example in the question, but for the sake of googlers it's worth pointing out that this is *not* always a safe technique for wider usage. Storing the values as object keys to count them means you're casting those values to strings and then counting that value. `[5, "5"]` will simply say you've got `"5"` two times. Or counting instances some different objects is just gonna tell you there's a lot of `[object Object]`. Etc. etc.

Comment: How could I then filter the returned object to show me highest to lowest, or lowest to highest count on a numbers

Comment: Very useful counter. Can easily be used in the reduce() method. Thanks!

Comment: why not:
`var arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
var counts = {};
arr.forEach(function(num) {
if (!(num in counts)) { counts[num] = 0; } counts[num]++; });
console.log(counts);`

This meets the OP's criteria of a way to get the unique values and the counts, but instead of using two separate arrays, a single object handles both requirements.

Comment: Note that elements in the array are always converted to a string when used as an object key. So when you would pass `[1, "1", { toString: () => "1" }]` you would give the result `{ 1: 3 }`

Comment: Can someone explain why the expression to execute if the condition is falsy (counts[num]) is 1 and not 0?

Answer (score 196):

```js
const occurrences = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4].reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  return acc[curr] ? ++acc[curr] : acc[curr] = 1, acc
}, {});

console.log(occurrences) // => {2: 5, 4: 1, 5: 3, 9: 1}
```

Comment: Thanks, very nice solution ;)
... and to get the "key" and "value" arrays:
`const keys = Object.keys(a);`
`const values = Object.values(a);`

Comment: Short hand: `acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1` instead of using `if/else`. You can check [the answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66002712/9071943)

Comment: Note that elements in the array are always converted to a string when used as an object key. So when you would pass `[1, "1", { toString: () => "1" }]` you would give the result `{ 1: 3 }`

Comment: @ase , What should I change to get like this : `num:2,occ:5`? thank you.

Answer (score 121):

One line ES6 solution. So many answers using object as a map but I can't see anyone using an actual [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```
const map = arr.reduce((acc, e) => acc.set(e, (acc.get(e) || 0) + 1), new Map());
```

Use [`map.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/keys) to get unique elements

Use [`map.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values) to get the occurrences

Use [`map.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/entries) to get the pairs [element, frequency]

```js
var arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4]

const map = arr.reduce((acc, e) => acc.set(e, (acc.get(e) || 0) + 1), new Map());

console.info([...map.keys()])
console.info([...map.values()])
console.info([...map.entries()])
```

Comment: I used this and It worked pretty fine!

Comment: I thought it'll let me use arbitrary objects as keys, but I see no way to tell it how to calculate an object id, so not of much help.

Comment: @x-yuri The question is not asking about objects specifically but, changing `e` to `e.id` should be sufficient. Also, I'm not sure if id is a property that should contain duplicates, as it helps us identify elements.

Comment: Yeah, the question is not about objects, so you're in a position to ignore my comment. But I came here looking for a solution to [my case](https://gist.github.com/x-yuri/10a30bade4b9580452bef07f12cb11fb). And `Map` looked promising, but in the end it turned out that it doesn't help much.

Answer (score 103):

If using underscore or lodash, this is the simplest thing to do:

```
_.countBy(array);
```

Such that:

```
_.countBy([5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4])
=> Object {2: 5, 4: 1, 5: 3, 9: 1}
```

As pointed out by others, you can then execute the `_.keys()` and `_.values()` functions on the result to get just the unique numbers, and their occurrences, respectively. But in my experience, the original object is much easier to deal with.

Comment: Just worth noting that with countBy it only includes items that exist in the list, so if you wanted to count items that may not exist in the list then you would need to handle the exception.  Or use lodash filter and length like this: `filter([true, true, true, false], function(m){return m==true}).length`.  This would just return 0 if no values exist.

Comment: Worth adding that you need: const _ = require("lodash")

Answer (score 69):

Don't use two arrays for the result, use an object:

```
a      = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
result = { };
for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    if(!result[a[i]])
        result[a[i]] = 0;
    ++result[a[i]];
}
```

Then `result` will look like:

```
{
    2: 5,
    4: 1,
    5: 3,
    9: 1
}
```

Answer (score 62):

How about an ECMAScript2015 option.

```
const a = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];

const aCount = new Map([...new Set(a)].map(
    x => [x, a.filter(y => y === x).length]
));
```

```
aCount.get(5)  // 3
aCount.get(2)  // 5
aCount.get(9)  // 1
aCount.get(4)  // 1
```

This example passes the input array to the [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) constructor creating a collection of **unique** values.  The [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) then expands these values into a new array so we can call `map` and translate this into a two-dimensional array of `[value, count]` pairs - i.e. the following structure:

```
Array [
   [5, 3],
   [2, 5],
   [9, 1],
   [4, 1]
]
```

The new array is then passed to the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) constructor resulting in an [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols) object:

```
Map {
    5 => 3,
    2 => 5,
    9 => 1,
    4 => 1
}
```

The great thing about a `Map` object is that it preserves data-types - that is to say `aCount.get(5)` will return `3` but `aCount.get("5")` will return `undefined`.  It also allows for **any** value / type to act as a key meaning this solution will also work with an array of objects.

```js
function frequencies(/* {Array} */ a){
    return new Map([...new Set(a)].map(
        x => [x, a.filter(y => y === x).length]
    ));
}

let foo = { value: 'foo' },
    bar = { value: 'bar' },
    baz = { value: 'baz' };

let aNumbers = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4],
    aObjects = [foo, bar, foo, foo, baz, bar];

frequencies(aNumbers).forEach((val, key) => console.log(key + ': ' + val));
frequencies(aObjects).forEach((val, key) => console.log(key.value + ': ' + val));
```

Comment: do you have by any chance an improved answer of this just for an object array? im having trouble trying to modify it for an object array, where you just create a new array/map/set in which you remove duplicates, and add a new value for the object, let say called "duplicatedCount: value".
i managed to remove duplicates in my nested objects array from this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/36744732

Comment: `Set` uses object references for uniqueness and offers no API for comparison of _"similar"_ objects.  If you want to use this approach for such a task you'd need some intermediate reduction function that guarantees an array of unique instances.  It's not the most efficient but I put together a quick [example here](https://jsbin.com/regefuc/edit?js,console).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but i actually solved it a lilttle bit differently. if you can see the answer i added here http://stackoverflow.com/a/43211561/4474900 i gave example of what i did. it works well, my case had a complex object needed comparing. dont know about the efficiency of my solution though

Comment: This might use nice new data structures but has runtime in O(*n²*) while there are plenty of simple algorithms here that solve it in O(*n*).

Answer (score 58):

I think this is the simplest way how to count occurrences with same value in array.

```
var a = [true, false, false, false];
a.filter(function(value){
    return value === false;
}).length
```

Comment: or `a.filter(value => !value).length` with the new js syntax

Comment: Doesn’t answer the question.

Answer (score 38):

```js
const data = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4]

function count(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev), {})
}

console.log(count(data))
```

Comment: Would anyone care to explain this (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev) ?

Comment: The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator#Processing_and_then_returning) “evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand”, so this increments the value of prev[curr] (or initialises it to 1), then returns prev.

Comment: but is the output an array?

Answer (score 36):

### *2021's version*

#### The more elegant way is using [`Logical nullish assignment (x ??= y)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment)  combined with [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) with O(n) time complexity.

The main idea is still using `Array#reduce()` to aggregate with output as `object` to get the highest performance *(both time and space complexity)* in terms of `searching` & `construct bunches of intermediate arrays` like other answers.

```js
const arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] ??= {[curr]: 0};
  acc[curr][curr]++;
  
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(result));
```

#### Clean & Refactor code

Using [**Comma operator (,)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) syntax.

> `The comma operator (,)` evaluates each of its operands (*from left to
> right*) and *returns the value of the last operand*.

```js
const arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];
const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr] = (acc[curr] || 0) + 1, acc), {});
console.log(result);
```

**Output**

```
{
  "2": 5,
  "4": 1,
  "5": 3,
  "9": 1
}
```

Comment: How can I get the highest tally from this object?

Comment: Could you pls give me your expected result? @kontenurban

Comment: This is a very nice answer. you could make it more concise with:
 `const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => (acc[curr] = -~(acc[curr]), acc), {});`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47546846/1659476 for an explanation.

Comment: Thanks @YoniRabinovitch.
`Bitwise` of your answer looks elegant & concise as well.

Answer (score 26):

If you favour a single liner.

`arr.reduce(function(countMap, word) {countMap[word] = ++countMap[word] || 1;return countMap}, {});`

**Edit (6/12/2015)**:
The Explanation from the inside out.
countMap is a map that maps a word with its frequency, which we can see the anonymous function. What reduce does is apply the function with arguments as all the array elements and countMap being passed as the return value of the last function call. The last parameter ({}) is the default value of countMap for the first function call.

Comment: You should explain this. that would make it a much better answer so people can learn how to use it in other use cases.

Comment: A single liner that just removes the linebreak that would usually follow `;`, `{` and `}`. ... OK. I think with that definition of a one liner we can write Conway's Game of Life as a "oneliner".

Answer (score 22):

ES6 version should be much simplifier (another one line solution)

```js
let arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
let acc = arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc.set(val, 1 + (acc.get(val) || 0)), new Map());

console.log(acc);
// output: Map { 5 => 3, 2 => 5, 9 => 1, 4 => 1 }
```

A Map instead of plain Object helping us to distinguish different type of elements, or else all counting are base on strings

Answer (score 12):

**Edit 2020**: this is a pretty old answer (nine years). Extending the native `prototype` will always generate [discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/comments/5ch66r/why_is_extending_native_objects_such_as_string/). Although I think the programmer is free to choose her own programming style, here's a (more modern) approach to the problem without extending `Array.prototype`:

```js
{
  // create array with some pseudo random values (1 - 5)
  const arr = Array.from({length: 100})
    .map( () => Math.floor(1 + Math.random() * 5) );
  // frequencies using a reducer
  const arrFrequencies = arr.reduce((acc, value) => 
      ({ ...acc, [value]: acc[value] + 1 || 1}), {} )
  console.log(arrFrequencies);    
  console.log(`Value 4 occurs ${arrFrequencies[4]} times in arrFrequencies`);

  // bonus: restore Array from frequencies
  const arrRestored = Object.entries(arrFrequencies)
    .reduce( (acc, [key, value]) => acc.concat(Array(value).fill(+key)), [] );
  console.log(arrRestored.join());  
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

The old (2011) answer: you could extend `Array.prototype`, like this:

```js
{
  Array.prototype.frequencies = function() {
    var l = this.length,
      result = {
        all: []
      };
    while (l--) {
      result[this[l]] = result[this[l]] ? ++result[this[l]] : 1;
    }
    // all pairs (label, frequencies) to an array of arrays(2)
    for (var l in result) {
      if (result.hasOwnProperty(l) && l !== 'all') {
        result.all.push([l, result[l]]);
      }
    }
    return result;
  };

  var freqs = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4].frequencies();
  console.log(`freqs[2]: ${freqs[2]}`); //=> 5
  
  // or
  var freqs = '1,1,2,one,one,2,2,22,three,four,five,three,three,five'
    .split(',')
    .frequencies();
    
  console.log(`freqs.three: ${freqs.three}`); //=> 3
  
// Alternatively you can utilize Array.map:

    Array.prototype.frequencies = function() {
      var freqs = {
        sum: 0
      };
      this.map(function(a) {
        if (!(a in this)) {
          this[a] = 1;
        } else {
          this[a] += 1;
        }
        this.sum += 1;
        return a;
      }, freqs);
      return freqs;
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 11):

A shorter version using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [tilde (`~`) operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT).

```js
const data = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];

function freq(nums) {
  return nums.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    acc[curr] = -~acc[curr];
    return acc;
  }, {});
}

console.log(freq(data));
```

Answer (score 9):

Based on [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5669730/960177) of [@adamse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/204218/adamse) and [@pmandell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1789518/pmandell) (which I upvote), in **ES6** you can do it in **one line**:

- **2017 edit**: I use `||` to reduce code size and make it more readable.

```js
var a=[7,1,7,2,2,7,3,3,3,7,,7,7,7];
alert(JSON.stringify(

a.reduce((r,k)=>{r[k]=1+r[k]||1;return r},{})

));
```

---

It can be used to **count characters**:

```js
var s="ABRACADABRA";
alert(JSON.stringify(

s.split('').reduce((a, c)=>{a[c]++?0:a[c]=1;return a},{})

));
```

Comment: It would be more readable if you used `|| 0`: `(r,k)=>{r[k]=(r[k]||0)+1;return r}`

Comment: You can do anything in one line in JavaScript.

Comment: And why is it a bad thing, @Ry-?

Comment: Sometimes it's more clear in several lines, other is clearer in one line. Althoug it's a matter of "taste".

Comment: I mean “in ES6 you can do it in one line” applies to every answer, and you could also do this in ES5 in one line.

Comment: It may apply or may not apply, but I don't see the point: This is not every answer, it's only one answer. And in one line with ES6 it's clearer than multiple lines, in ES5 I think it's not (if you think it is, be free to post your answer).

Answer (score 8):

If you are using underscore you can go the functional route

```
a = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar'];

var results = _.reduce(a,function(counts,key){ counts[key]++; return counts },
                  _.object( _.map( _.uniq(a), function(key) { return [key, 0] })))
```

so your first array is

```
_.keys(results)
```

and the second array is

```
_.values(results)
```

most of this will default to native javascript functions if they are available

demo : http://jsfiddle.net/dAaUU/

Answer (score 7):

```
var array = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];

function countDuplicates(obj, num){
  obj[num] = (++obj[num] || 1);
  return obj;
}

var answer = array.reduce(countDuplicates, {});
// answer => {2:5, 4:1, 5:3, 9:1};
```

> If you still want **two** arrays, then you could use *answer* like this...

```
var uniqueNums = Object.keys(answer);
// uniqueNums => ["2", "4", "5", "9"];

var countOfNums = Object.keys(answer).map(key => answer[key]);
// countOfNums => [5, 1, 3, 1];
```

> Or if you want uniqueNums to be numbers

```
var uniqueNums = Object.keys(answer).map(key => +key);
// uniqueNums => [2, 4, 5, 9];
```

Comment: es6/7 makes this all much nicer. You may also want to reduce to a `Map` instead, since it will avoid the typecasting that using a number as an object key (casting as string) does. `const answer = array.reduce((a, e) => a.set(e, (a.get(e) || 0) + 1), new Map())` .You can get `answer.keys()` for the keys, and `answer.values()` for the values as arrays. `[...answer]` will give you a big array with all the key/values as 2d arrays.

Answer (score 7):

So here's how I'd do it with some of the newest javascript features:

First, reduce the array to a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) of the counts:

```
let countMap = array.reduce(
  (map, value) => {map.set(value, (map.get(value) || 0) + 1); return map}, 
  new Map()
)
```

By using a `Map`, your starting array can contain any type of object, and the counts will be correct. Without a `Map`, some types of objects will give you strange counts.
See the [`Map` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for more info on the differences.

This could also be done with an object if all your values are symbols, numbers, or strings:

```
let countObject = array.reduce(
  (map, value) => { map[value] = (map[value] || 0) + 1; return map },
  {}
)
```

Or slightly fancier in a functional way without mutation, using destructuring and object spread syntax:

```
let countObject = array.reduce(
  (value, {[value]: count = 0, ...rest}) => ({ [value]: count + 1, ...rest }),
  {}
)
```

At this point, you can use the `Map` or object for your counts (and the map is directly iterable, unlike an object), or convert it to two arrays.

For the `Map`:

```
countMap.forEach((count, value) => console.log(`value: ${value}, count: ${count}`)

let values = countMap.keys()
let counts = countMap.values()
```

Or for the object:

```
Object
  .entries(countObject) // convert to array of [key, valueAtKey] pairs
  .forEach(([value, count]) => console.log(`value: ${value}, count: ${count}`)

let values = Object.keys(countObject)
let counts = Object.values(countObject)
```

Comment: "Without a Map, some types of objects will give you strange counts" +1 for explaining how a map is better than an Object.

Answer (score 6):

Here's just something light and easy for the eyes...

```
function count(a,i){
 var result = 0;
 for(var o in a)
  if(a[o] == i)
   result++;
 return result;
}
```

**Edit:** And since you want all the occurences...

```
function count(a){
 var result = {};
 for(var i in a){
  if(result[a[i]] == undefined) result[a[i]] = 0;
  result[a[i]]++;
 }
 return result;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Solution using a map with **O(n)** time complexity.

```
var arr = [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5, 9];

const countOccurrences = (arr) => {
    const map = {};
    for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        map[arr[i]] = ~~map[arr[i]] + 1;
    }
    return map;
}
```

Demo: [http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/bnACW/](https://jsfiddle.net/svaqqosov/8jdnhgsz/23/)

Comment: My upvote to you, this works like butter with O(n) time complexity

Comment: I timed many answers from this thread (link https://jsbench.me/2wkzzagdu3/1 and this was the fastest). I imagine even without the bit twiddling, it would be similarly fast, just given the plain for loop. The lodash solution is 9% slower, and without the tilde tilde and replace with (map[arr[i]] || 0) it is also 9% slower. Other answers are much slower than this one.

Answer (score 3):

There is a much better and easy way that we can do this using `ramda.js`.
[Code sample here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.23.0#?const%20ary%20%3D%20%5B5%2C%205%2C%205%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%2C%209%2C%204%5D%3B%0AR.countBy%28r%3D%3E%20r%29%28ary%29)

`const ary = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
R.countBy(r=> r)(ary)`

countBy documentation is at [documentation](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#countBy)

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old but I realized there are too few solutions where you get the count array as asked with a minimal code so here is mine

```js
// The initial array we want to count occurences
var initial = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];  

// The count array asked for
var count = Array.from(new Set(initial)).map(val => initial.filter(v => v === val).length);  

// Outputs [ 3, 5, 1, 1 ]
```

Beside you can get the set from that initial array with

```js
var set = Array.from(new Set(initial));  

//set = [5, 2, 9, 4]
```

Comment: This code is terribly inefficient as it iterates on the initial array length^2 times.

Comment: Yes this code is `length²` time complex, that's why I insisted its aim is to provide a **minimal code** that solves that problem!

Answer (score 3):

To return an array which is then sortable:

```js
let array = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4]
let reducedArray = array.reduce( (acc, curr, _, arr) => {
    if (acc.length == 0) acc.push({item: curr, count: 1})
    else if (acc.findIndex(f => f.item === curr ) === -1) acc.push({item: curr, count: 1})
    else ++acc[acc.findIndex(f => f.item === curr)].count
    return acc
}, []);

console.log(reducedArray.sort((a,b) => b.count - a.count ))

/*
  Output:
  [
    {
      "item": 2,
      "count": 5
    },
    {
      "item": 5,
      "count": 3
    },
    {
      "item": 9,
      "count": 1
    },
    {
      "item": 4,
      "count": 1
    }
  ]

*/
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution with ramda:

```
const testArray = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4]

const counfFrequency = R.compose(
  R.map(R.length),
  R.groupBy(R.identity),
)

counfFrequency(testArray)
```

[Link to REPL.](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?const%20testArray%20%3D%20%5B5%2C%205%2C%205%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%2C%202%2C%209%2C%204%5D%0A%0Aconst%20counfFrequency%20%3D%20R.compose%28%0A%20%20R.map%28R.length%29%2C%0A%20%20R.groupBy%28R.identity%29%2C%0A%29%0A%0AcounfFrequency%28testArray%29)

Answer (score 2):

Using **[MAP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/has)** you can have 2 arrays in the output: One containing the occurrences & the other one is containing the number of occurrences.

```js
const dataset = [2,2,4,2,6,4,7,8,5,6,7,10,10,10,15];
let values = [];
let keys = [];

var mapWithOccurences = dataset.reduce((a,c) => {
  if(a.has(c)) a.set(c,a.get(c)+1);
  else a.set(c,1);
  return a;
}, new Map())
.forEach((value, key, map) => {
  keys.push(key);
  values.push(value);
});


console.log(keys)
console.log(values)
```

Answer (score 2):

This question is **more than 8 years old** and many, many answers do not really **take ES6 and its numerous advantages into account.**

Perhaps is even more important to **think about** the consequences of our code for **garbage collection/memory management** whenever we create additional arrays, make double or triple copies of arrays or even convert arrays into objects. These are trivial observations for small applications but if scale is a long term objective then think about these, thoroughly.

If you just need a "counter" for specific data types and the starting point is an array (I assume you want therefore an ordered list and take advantage of the many properties and methods arrays offer), you can just simply iterate through array1 and populate array2 with the values and number of occurrences for these values found in array1.

*As simple as that.*

Example of simple class SimpleCounter (ES6) for **Object Oriented Programming** and **Object Oriented Design**

```
class SimpleCounter { 

    constructor(rawList){ // input array type
        this.rawList = rawList;
        this.finalList = [];
    }

    mapValues(){ // returns a new array

        this.rawList.forEach(value => {
            this.finalList[value] ? this.finalList[value]++ : this.finalList[value] = 1;
        });

        this.rawList = null; // remove array1 for garbage collection

        return this.finalList;

    }

}

module.exports = SimpleCounter;
```

Comment: Sticking a function in a class for no reason doesn’t make it object-oriented, `finalList` has no reason to be an array, and this has no advantages over doing it properly.

Answer (score 2):

Using Lodash

```js
const values = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
const frequency = _.map(_.groupBy(values), val => ({ value: val[0], frequency: val.length }));
console.log(frequency);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Given the array supplied below:

```js
const array = [ 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c' ];
```

You can use this simple one-liner to generate a hash map which links a key to the number of times it appears in the array:

```js
const hash = Object.fromEntries([ ...array.reduce((map, key) => map.set(key, (map.get(key) || 0) + 1), new Map()) ]);
// { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }
```

Expanded & Explained:

```js
// first, we use reduce to generate a map with values and the amount of times they appear
const map = array.reduce((map, key) => map.set(key, (map.get(key) || 0) + 1), new Map())

// next, we spread this map into an array
const table = [ ...map ];

// finally, we use Object.fromEntries to generate an object based on this entry table
const result = Object.fromEntries(table);
```

credit to [@corashina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7306664/corashina) for the `array.reduce` code

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code below.

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
// array with values
var ar = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];

var Unique = []; // we'll store a list of unique values in here
var Counts = []; // we'll store the number of occurances in here

for(var i in ar)
{
    var Index = ar[i];
    Unique[Index] = ar[i];
    if(typeof(Counts[Index])=='undefined')  
        Counts[Index]=1;
    else
        Counts[Index]++;
}

// remove empty items
Unique = Unique.filter(function(){ return true});
Counts = Counts.filter(function(){ return true});

alert(ar.join(','));
alert(Unique.join(','));
alert(Counts.join(','));

var a=[];

for(var i=0; i<Unique.length; i++)
{
    a.push(Unique[i] + ':' + Counts[i] + 'x');
}
alert(a.join(', '));

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify this a bit by extending your arrays with a `count` function. It works similar to [Ruby’s `Array#count`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.2/Array.html#method-i-count), if you’re familiar with it.

```
Array.prototype.count = function(obj){
  var count = this.length;
  if(typeof(obj) !== "undefined"){
    var array = this.slice(0), count = 0; // clone array and reset count
    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
      if(array[i] == obj){ count++ }
    }
  }
  return count;
}
```

Usage:

```
let array = ['a', 'b', 'd', 'a', 'c'];
array.count('a'); // => 2
array.count('b'); // => 1
array.count('e'); // => 0
array.count(); // => 5
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/zykadelic/5069223#file-array-count-js)

---

#### Edit

You can then get your first array, with each occurred item, using `Array#filter`:

```
let occurred = [];
array.filter(function(item) {
  if (!occurred.includes(item)) {
    occurred.push(item);
    return true;
  }
}); // => ["a", "b", "d", "c"]
```

And your second array, with the number of occurrences, using `Array#count` into `Array#map`:

```
occurred.map(array.count.bind(array)); // => [2, 1, 1, 1]
```

Alternatively, if order is irrelevant, you can just return it as a key-value pair:

```
let occurrences = {}
occurred.forEach(function(item) { occurrences[item] = array.count(item) });
occurences; // => {2: 5, 4: 1, 5: 3, 9: 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function countOcurrences(arr){
    return arr.reduce((aggregator, value, index, array) => {
      if(!aggregator[value]){
        return aggregator = {...aggregator, [value]: 1};  
      }else{
        return aggregator = {...aggregator, [value]:++aggregator[value]};
      }
    }, {})
}
```

Comment: Extremely wasteful to copy the object every time. Creates a quadratic worst case when it could be linear.

Answer (score 0):

I was solving a similar problem on codewars and devised the following solution which worked for me.

This gives the highest count of an integer in an array and also the integer itself. I think it can be applied to string array as well.

To properly sort Strings, remove the `function(a, b){return a-b}` from inside the `sort()` portion

```
function mostFrequentItemCount(collection) {
    collection.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
    var i=0;
    var ans=[];
    var int_ans=[];
    while(i<collection.length)
    {
        if(collection[i]===collection[i+1])
        {
            int_ans.push(collection[i]);
        }
        else
        {
            int_ans.push(collection[i]);
            ans.push(int_ans);
            int_ans=[];
        }
        i++;
    }

    var high_count=0;
    var high_ans;

    i=0;
    while(i<ans.length)
    {
        if(ans[i].length>high_count)
        {
            high_count=ans[i].length;
            high_ans=ans[i][0];
        }
        i++;
    }
    return high_ans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to count occurrences inside an array of objects. It also places the first array's contents inside a new array to sort the values so that the order in the original array is not disrupted. Then a recursive function is used to go through each element and count the quantity property of each object inside the array.

```
var big_array = [
  { name: "Pineapples", quantity: 3 },
  { name: "Pineapples", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Bananas", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Limes", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Bananas", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Pineapples", quantity: 2 },
  { name: "Pineapples", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Bananas", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Bananas", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Bananas", quantity: 5 },
  { name: "Coconuts", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Lemons", quantity: 2 },
  { name: "Oranges", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Lemons", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Limes", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Grapefruit", quantity: 1 },
  { name: "Coconuts", quantity: 5 },
  { name: "Oranges", quantity: 6 }
];

function countThem() {
  var names_array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < big_array.length; i++) {
    names_array.push( Object.assign({}, big_array[i]) );
  }

  function outerHolder(item_array) {
    if (item_array.length > 0) {
      var occurrences = [];
      var counter = 0;
      var bgarlen = item_array.length;
      item_array.sort(function(a, b) { return (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0); });

      function recursiveCounter() {
        occurrences.push(item_array[0]);
        item_array.splice(0, 1);
        var last_occurrence_element = occurrences.length - 1;
        var last_occurrence_entry = occurrences[last_occurrence_element].name;
        var occur_counter = 0;
        var quantity_counter = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < occurrences.length; i++) {
          if (occurrences[i].name === last_occurrence_entry) {
            occur_counter = occur_counter + 1;
            if (occur_counter === 1) {
              quantity_counter = occurrences[i].quantity;
            } else {
              quantity_counter = quantity_counter + occurrences[i].quantity;
            }
          }
        }

        if (occur_counter > 1) {
          var current_match = occurrences.length - 2;
          occurrences[current_match].quantity = quantity_counter;
          occurrences.splice(last_occurrence_element, 1);
        }

        counter = counter + 1;

        if (counter < bgarlen) {
          recursiveCounter();
        }
      }

      recursiveCounter();

      return occurrences;
    }
  }
  alert(JSON.stringify(outerHolder(names_array)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its easy with filter

In this example we simply assign count, the length of the array filtered by the key you're looking for

```
let array = [{name: "steve", age: 22}, {name: "bob", age: 30}]

let count = array.filter(obj => obj.name === obj.name).length

console.log(count)
```

more on JS Filiters here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

```
var aa = [1,3,5,7,3,2,4,6,8,1,3,5,5,2,0,6,5,9,6,3,5,2,5,6,8];
var newArray = {};
for(var element of aa){
  if(typeof newArray[element] === 'undefined' || newArray[element] === null){
    newArray[element] = 1;
  }else{
    newArray[element] +=1;
  }
}

for ( var element in newArray){
  console.log( element +" -> "+ newArray[element]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the questions specifically asks to have two resulting arrays, which I haven't seen, so here's my solution:

```
const theArray = [1, 3425, 56, 7, 9, 5, 4, 3425, 7, 7, 7];

const uniqueVals = [...new Set(theArray)];
const countPerUniqueValArray = uniqueVals.map(uv => theArray.filter(i => i === uv).length);

console.log(uniqueVals);
console.log(countPerUniqueValArray);

// Expect:
// [1, 3425, 56, 7, 9, 5, 4]
// [1, 2, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4] 
function countAndSort(arr) { 
    return Object.entries(arr.reduce((prev, curr) => (prev[curr] = ++prev[curr] || 1, prev), {})).sort((a,b) => b[1]-a[1])
} 
console.log(countAndSort(data))
```

Comment: The return format seems pretty awkward -- a list of lists where each inner list is a key and a count.

Answer (score 0):

let numberArray = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];

We'll use Reduce method to count the occurrence from array

const uniqueIntArray = numberArray.reduce((x: any, y: any) => ((x[y] = (x[y] || 0) + 1 ), x), {})

console.log('uniqueIntArray ', uniqueIntArray);
{
"2": 5,
"4": 1,
"5": 3,
"9": 1
}

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
const findOccurance = (arr) => {
let resultObj={};
let sortedArr = arr.sort();
let uniqueArrVal = [...new Set(sortedArr)]

uniqueArrVal.forEach(e=> resultObj[e]=(sortedArr.lastIndexOf(e)-sortedArr.indexOf(e))+1)
return resultObj;
}

console.log(findOccurance (['a','b','a']))
console.log(findOccurance ([1,98,5,1,6,'a','f','a',98]))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want the output with key as the number and value as the count (i.e) get an obj returned like this {a:1, b:2} for the input ['a','b','a'], then here is the code

```
    const findOccurance = (arr) => {
    let resultObj={};
    let sortedArr = arr.sort();
    let uniqueArrVal = [...new Set(sortedArr)]
    
    uniqueArrVal.forEach(e=> resultObj[e]=(sortedArr.lastIndexOf(e)-sortedArr.indexOf(e))+1)
    return resultObj;
    }
console.log(findOccurance (['a','b','a']))
console.log(findOccurance ([1,98,5,1,6,'a','f','a',98]))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Array.prototype.getItemCount = function(item) {
    var counts = {};
    for(var i = 0; i< this.length; i++) {
        var num = this[i];
        counts[num] = counts[num] ? counts[num]+1 : 1;
    }
    return counts[item] || 0;
}
```

Comment: getItemCount doesn't need to create an array if it only counts a single item. Either make it getItemCounts and return `counts`, or only count occurrences of `item`.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a classic old school method for counting arrays.

```
var arr = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4];
var counted = [], count = [];
var i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
while (k < arr.length) {
    if (counted.indexOf(arr[k]) < 0) {
        counted[i] = arr[k];
        count[i] = 0;
        for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (counted[i] == arr[j]) {
                count[i]++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    } else {
        k++;
    }
}
```

You can sort it first if you want an alphabetical result, but if you want to preserve the order in which the data was entered then give this a try. Nested loops may be a bit slower than some of the other methods on this page.

Answer (score -1):

```
const arr = [2, 2, 5, 2, 2, 2, 4, 5, 5, 9]
const arrCount: { value: number; count: number }[] = []

arr.sort()

arr.map((ele) => {
     const existingCount = arrCount.find((existingEntry) => {
         return existingEntry.value === ele
     })

     if (!existingCount) arrCount.push({ value: ele, count: 1 })
     else existingCount.count++
})

console.log(arrCount)
```