# Javascript, arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, join, count

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Counting occurences of Javascript array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-occurences-of-javascript-array-elements)

I have an array in javascript and for example the array is:

```
array(1,1,1,1,5,5,7,7);
```

If can some one please help me to understand how to count similar values,
And how to join similar values,
Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: by _join similar values_, do you mean to _combine_ them into one unique value?

Comment: It seems to be sorted already. Can't you image a simple algorithm to do what you want? Hint: use a loop.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-occurences-of-javascript-array-elements

Comment: it is better to show what you have tried or describe what you are thinking about doing. You will get much better responses that way

Comment: If you don't understand something, do a little reading and try something out first. SO is better suited to help you with a specific question, with a little more [effort shown in the question](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Thank you all ill read the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to uniquely identify array contents:

```
Array.prototype.unique =
  function() {
    var a = [];
    var l = this.length;
    for(var i=0; i<l; i++) {
      for(var j=i+1; j<l; j++) {
        // If this[i] is found later in the array
        if (this[i] === this[j])
          j = ++i;
      }
      a.push(this[i]);
    }
    return a;
  };

  var myArray = [1,1,1,1,5,5,7,7];

  var uniquedMyArray = myArray.unique();
  var valueCountsMyArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
     if (valueCountsMyArray[myArray[i]])
        valueCountsMyArray[myArray[i]]++;
     else
        valueCountsMyArray[myArray[i]] = 1;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you J Torres, have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

```
var array = [1,1,1,1,5,5,7,7];

var count = 0;
var tempArray = array.sort();
var i;
var prevValue = null;
var joined = [];
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

    if (tempArray[i] != prevValue) {
        count++;
        prevValue = tempArray[i];
        joined.push(prevValue);
    }

}

​document.write(joined);​
```

Comment: Link to my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mJ7vp/

Comment: count variable contains count of similar elements

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org).  The code you're looking for isn't hard to write, and would be a good learning experience.  Once you've done that, underscore is fantastic convenience library that offers what you're looking for, and you don't have to maintain it. :)

The [uniq](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) function will give you a copy of your array without duplicates, and the [size](http://underscorejs.org/#size) function will tell you how many values that contains (or just reference the `.length` property).

Comment: Ah, yes, the "let's incorporate another library for every simple function we need to do" approach to web development.

Comment: That's what libraries are for.

Comment: Suggesting a library is not an answer to a specific question as this. Unless OP asked how to do it with underscore, it is not on topic.

Comment: A +1. Because it isn't deserving of a -1. It answers how the problem can be solved in JS. Said library is still JS and the poster did not request "no libraries" .. although showing how it to solve in vanilla JS might be better for this posters level of experience :)

Comment: @pst: It's really too bad when people support off topic answers. Unless we know OP is using a library, such an answer is not helpful. By this standard, questions could be cluttered with dozens of answers that are unhelpful to the asker. Lest you forget, StackOverflow is not a discussion forum. Sadly, it's turning more and more into one

Comment: @pst ...an asker should not have to explicitly state that no library answer is desired. It's silly to put such a requirement on every question that simply wants a direct and on-topic answer to the question.

Comment: @amnotiam This discussion really belongs on meta, not SO.

Comment: This is specific to your post. @pst upvoted it even though it makes no attempt to answer the question, and the second paragraph doesn't even help OP count the similar values as requested.

Comment: From the question: ***"...please help me to understand how to..."***

Comment: @amnotiam Very good arguments. I would not have upvoted if not a -1. But still, the -1 seemed .. wrong somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution to count how many time it contains a number.

```
var count = [];
for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    count[array[i]]++;
}
```

Comment: Does not work without initialisation. Also, I'd recommend using an object instead of an array.

Comment: Not quite: `undefined++` -> `NaN`