# Finding out how many times an array element appears

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to JavaScript, I have been learning and practicing for about 3 months and hope I can get some help on this topic. I'm making a poker game and what I'm trying to do is determine whether i have a pair, two pairs, three of a kind, four of a kind or a full house.

For instance, in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3]`, 1 appears one time, 4 appears three times, and so on.

How could I possibly ask my computer to tell me how many times an array element appears?

Solved, here's the final product.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var deck = [];
    var cards = [];
    var convertedcards = [];
    var kinds = [];
    var phase = 1;
    var displaycard = [];
    var options = 0;
    var endgame = false;

    // Fill Deck //
    for(i = 0; i < 52; i++){
        deck[deck.length] = i;          
    }

    // Distribute Cards //
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        cards[cards.length] = Number(Math.floor(Math.random() * 52));
        if(deck.indexOf(cards[cards.length - 1]) === -1){
            cards.splice(cards.length - 1, cards.length);
            i = i - 1;
        }else{
            deck[cards[cards.length - 1]] = "|";
        }
    }

    // Convert Cards //
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        convertedcards[i] = (cards[i] % 13) + 1;
    }


    // Cards Kind //
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        if(cards[i] < 13){
            kinds[kinds.length] = "H";
        }else if(cards[i] < 27 && cards[i] > 12){
            kinds[kinds.length] = "C";
        }else if(cards[i] < 40 && cards[i] > 26){
            kinds[kinds.length] = "D";
        }else{
            kinds[kinds.length] = "S";
        }
    }

    // Card Display //
    for(i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        displaycard[i] = convertedcards[i] + kinds[i];
    }

    // Hand Strenght //
    var handstrenght = function(){
        var usedcards = [];
        var count = 0;
        var pairs = [];
        for(i = 0, a = 1; i < 7; a++){
            if(convertedcards[i] === convertedcards[a] && a < 7 && usedcards[i] != "|"){
                pairs[pairs.length] = convertedcards[i];
                usedcards[a] = "|";
            }else if(a > 6){
                i = i + 1;
                a = i;
            }
        }

        // Flush >.< //
        var flush = false;
        for(i = 0, a = 1; i < 7; i++, a++){
            if(kinds[i] === kinds[a] && kinds[i] != undefined){
                count++;
                if(a >= 6 && count >= 5){
                    flush = true;
                    count = 0;
                }else if(a >= 6 && count < 5){
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        // Straight >.< //
        var straight = false;
        convertedcards = convertedcards.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
        if(convertedcards[2] > 10 && convertedcards[3] > 10 && convertedcards[4] > 10){
            convertedcards[0] = 14;
            convertedcards = convertedcards.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
        }
        alert(convertedcards);
        if(convertedcards[0] + 1 === convertedcards[1] && convertedcards[1] + 1 === convertedcards[2] && convertedcards[2] + 1 === convertedcards[3] && convertedcards[3] + 1 === convertedcards[4]){
            straight = true;
        }else if(convertedcards[1] + 1 === convertedcards[2] && convertedcards[2] + 1 === convertedcards[3] && convertedcards[3] + 1 === convertedcards[4] && convertedcards[4] + 1 === convertedcards[5]){
            straight = true;
        }else if(convertedcards[2] + 1 === convertedcards[3] && convertedcards[3] + 1 === convertedcards[4] && convertedcards[4] + 1 === convertedcards[5] && convertedcards[5] + 1 === convertedcards[6]){
            straight = true;
        }
        // Royal Flush, Straight Flush, Flush, Straight >.< //
        var royalflush = false;
        if(straight === true && flush === true && convertedcards[6] === 14){
            royalflush = true;
            alert("You have a Royal Flush");
        }
        else if(straight === true && flush === true && royalflush === false){
            alert("You have a straight flush");
        }else if(straight === true && flush === false){
            alert("You have a straight");
        }else if(straight === false && flush === true){
            alert("You have a flush");
        }
        // Full House >.< //
        if(pairs[0] === pairs[1] && pairs[1] != pairs[2] && pairs.length >= 3){
            fullhouse = true;
            alert("You have a fullhouse");
        }else if(pairs[0] != pairs[1] && pairs[1] === pairs[2] && pairs.length >= 3){
            fullhouse = true;
            alert("You have a fullhouse");
        }else if(pairs[0] != pairs[1] && pairs[1] != pairs[2] && pairs[2] === pairs[3] && pairs.length >= 3){
            fullhouse = true;
            alert("You have a fullhouse");
        }
        // Four of a kind >.< //
        else if(pairs[0] === pairs[1] && pairs[1] === pairs[2] && pairs.length > 0){
            alert("You have four of a kind");
        }
        // Three of a kind >.< //
        else if(pairs[0] === pairs[1] && flush === false && straight === false && pairs.length === 2){
            alert("You have three of a kind");
        }
        // Double Pair >.< //
        else if(pairs[0] != pairs[1] && flush === false && straight === false && pairs.length > 1){
            alert("You have a double pair");
        }
        // Pair >.< //
        else if(pairs.length === 1 && flush === false && straight === false && pairs.length === 1 ){
            alert("You have a pair");
        }
        alert(pairs);
    };
    while(endgame === false){
        if(phase === 1){
            options = Number(prompt("Your hand: " + displaycard[0] + " " + displaycard[1] + "\n\n" + "1. Check" + "\n" + "2. Fold"));
        }else if(phase === 2){
            options = Number(prompt("Your hand: " + displaycard[0] + " " + displaycard[1] + "\n\n" + displaycard[2] + " " + displaycard[3] + " " + displaycard[4] + "\n\n" + "1. Check" + "\n" + "2. Fold"));
        }else if(phase === 3){
            options = Number(prompt("Your hand: " + displaycard[0] + " " + displaycard[1] + "\n\n" + displaycard[2] + " " + displaycard[3] + " " + displaycard[4] + " " + displaycard[5] + "\n\n" + "1. Check" + "\n" + "2. Fold"));
        }else if(phase === 4){
            options = Number(prompt("Your hand: " + displaycard[0] + " " + displaycard[1] + "\n\n" + displaycard[2] + " " + displaycard[3] + " " + displaycard[4] + " " + displaycard[5] + " " + displaycard[6] + "\n\n" + "1. Check" + "\n" + "2. Fold"));
        }
        switch(options){
            case 1:
                    if(phase === 5){
                        handstrenght();
                        endgame = true;
                    }else{
                        phase++;
                    }
                    break;
            case 2:
                    endgame = true;
                    break;
            default:
                    endgame = true;
                    break;
        }
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Don't want to just give this secret away or keep you from a learning experience ;)

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you know how to do a `for` loop?

Comment: @JuanMendes I would up vote your comment 20 times if I could :-).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

- Keep a variable for the total count
- Loop through the array and check if current value is the same as the one you're looking for, if it is, increment the total count by one
- After the loop, total count contains the number of times the number you were looking for is in the array

Show your code and we can help you figure out where it went wrong

Here's a simple implementation (since you don't have the code that didn't work)

```
var list = [2, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 4, 5];  

function countInArray(array, what) {
    var count = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] === what) {
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}

countInArray(list, 2); // returns 2
countInArray(list, 1); // returns 3
```

countInArray could also have been implemented as

```
function countInArray(array, what) {
    return array.filter(item => item == what).length;
}
```

More elegant, but maybe not as performant since it has to create a new array.

Comment: Good, if this is the solution, my idea was right but the code isn't.

I'll figure it out.

Comment: @FredericDaniel Show your code, questions here at SO should always show code, expected/actual results and any error messages

Comment: My code doesn't exist anymore, i got mad 1 month ago after trying to fix this problem for 6 hours straight and deleted the project.

Comment: Then try it again and post it here if you can't get it to work, don't just give up

Comment: Here's the code and I'm still stuck at the same place. [1,1,2,2,3,3,5] works but [1,2,1,2,3,3,5] doesn't. Awesome

Comment: Nevermind, all i had to do was make an else if to see if 'a' was greater than 6. Everything works now.

Comment: @Dake How about you write one and ask another question if you have a problem?

Answer (score 14):

With `filter` and `length` it seems simple but there is a big waste of memory.

If you want to use nice array methods, the appropriate one is `reduce`:

```js
function countInArray(array, value) {
  return array.reduce((n, x) => n + (x === value), 0);
}
console.log(countInArray([1,2,3,4,4,4,3], 4)); // 3
```

Comment: `big waste of memory` - can you elaborate why?

Comment: btw, this is genius!

Answer (score 4):

Well..

```
var a = [5, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 9, 4].reduce(function (acc, curr) {
  if (typeof acc[curr] == 'undefined') {
    acc[curr] = 1;
  } else {
    acc[curr] += 1;
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

// a == {2: 5, 4: 1, 5: 3, 9: 1}
```

from here:
[Counting the occurrences of JavaScript array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-occurences-of-javascript-array-elements)

Or you can find other solutions there, too..

Comment: Nice sophisticated answer, but I think this may be a bit over the OP's head. At least it doesn't give the answer away, since it will still take a lot of learning for the OP to understand what is happening. On the other hand, they may use your method without ever understanding it, which would defeat the point of SO.

Answer (score 2):

When targeting recent enough browsers, you can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter). (The MDN page also provides a polyfill for the function.)

```
var items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3];
var fours = items.filter(function(it) {return it === 4;});
var result = fours.length;
```

You can even abstract over the filtering function as this:

```
// Creates a new function that returns true if the parameter passed to it is 
// equal to `x`
function equal_func(x) {
    return function(it) {
        return it === x;
    }
}
//...
var result = items.filter(equal_func(4)).length;
```

Comment: It's supported since IE9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @JuanMendes - Thanks, I made the phrasing of the answer more accurate.

Comment: This wastes too much memory.

Comment: @Oriol It uses O(N) memory, worst-case, for presumably tiny values of N, the memory overhead is completely irrelevant in a practical context. If you can't spare that much memory, you probably can't store the original array. If you need to process vast dataset and are looking to SO answers to school assignment questions for hits you've got worse problems.

Comment: A reduce-based version would be more efficient, but reduces aren't too readable at what I guessed the OP's skill level to be, and a loop version is already the accepted answer, so I'm not going to edit a 4-year old answer to make it substantially different than what was voted for unless it's patently wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation of Juan's answer:

```
function count( list, x ) {

    for ( var l = list.length, c = 0; l--; ) {

        if ( list[ l ] === x ) {

            c++;
        }
    }

    return c;

}
```

Even shorter:

```
function count( list, x ) {

    for ( var l = list.length, c = 0; l--; list[ l ] === x && c++ );

    return c;

}
```

Comment: Why trying to make it short? Make it simple, no need for optimizations. Also, if you make it a method, you have to pass the array in, please don't rely on a global.

Comment: @JuanMendes I'm not passing an array in, just the value. `list` is the array the OP declares in his question... :)

Comment: My point is that you should be passing it in. `count` should take the array to count as an argument instead of using a global. Otherwise it makes no sense to make it a function since it can only work with that global you setup. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation that uses the Array Object Prototype and has an extra level of functionality that returns the length if no search-item is supplied:

```
Array.prototype.count = function(lit = false) {
    if ( !lit ) { return this.length}
    else {
        var count = 0;
        for ( var i=0; i < this.length; i++ ) {
            if ( lit == this[i] ){
                count++
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

---

This has an extremely simple useage, and is as follows:

```
var count = [1,2,3,4,4].count(4);  // Returns 2
var count = [1,2,3,4,4].count();   // Without first parameter returns 5
```

Comment: Avoid messing with the prototype of native objects, it may be incompatible when an `Array.prototype.count` method is standardized.

Comment: This returns 3 for `[1,2,3].count(0)` I would get rid of the case where you're just returning length

Answer (score 0):

Avoid messing with the prototype of native objects, it may be incompatible when an Array.prototype.count method is standardized.