# Using a 'for' loop to count how many times a specific number appears in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

just started learning JS and had a test about loops and wasn't successful in finding an answer to this:
I would like to see how many times the number 1 appears in the arrray.
All i was able to do is get a true answer when 1 appears in the array.
Been trying to figure this out since last Wednesday..
Thanks!

```
var v = [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

count = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++){

      console.log (count == v[i])

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389398/finding-out-how-many-times-an-array-element-appears

Comment: Studying some array tutorials and doing some searching would help. Basic research is expected before asking questions here

Comment: `count == v[i]` The reason this comes back as true is that its a like the same as saying `Is count the same value as the value in the index?` so if count = 1 and v[i] = 1 then that question above would have an answer of true.

Comment: @charlietfl, i used some array tutorials and loop tutorials but wasn't able to understand it thoroughly, As i'm trying to understand the questions that appeared in the test i had.

Comment: @ollie Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to count the number of times a value appears in the array, you firstly need to initialise a variable outside of the loop (if you initialise in the loop, the value will be reset on each iteration of that loop). 
Secondly you need a conditional statement that you will check for, in this case if a value is equal to one. As its a loop, and more then one value in the array, we can get the current index's value like `v[i]` (which you correctly did). Now you need to plus one to your counter, `counter++` is the same as `counter = counter + 1;`. Now the if statement i used below has the `===` this is an equals operator that also check to see if the two values are of the same type.

```
  var v = [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];    
    var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
            if(v[i] === 1){
                count++;
            }
        }
          console.log (count);
```

Comment: Thanks!!!
Do you know any other option to do so without using the if?

Comment: I would take a look at @Agalo answer

Comment: @Yair Check out my second example. It removes the loop and the `if`.

Comment: *"you firstly need to initialise a variable outside of the loop"* The OP was doing that already. Also, Agalo's answer is still relying of `if` of sorts when `===` is used.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the `filter` method which returns the array with specified condition and then you can do a count by using the `length` property.

```js
var v = [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];
console.log((v.filter(x => x === 1)).length);
```

Comment: Does the same job, but for someone starting to learn JS... might be too advanced, but thats my opinion.

Comment: learning method like `forEach, map, find, filter etc` would definitely help in writing concise and clear code.

Comment: for counting an item, creating a new array is a bit over the top.

Comment: Yes, this works, but as others have stated, for a newbie, it's too complex. It also doesn't really address why the OPs code doesn't work and it is excessive for such a simple task.

Comment: @NinaScholz - Curios to know which method would you suggest which would be more efficient in terms of performance and space.

Comment: you could use reduce and add the condition expression.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question at all, which specifically asks how to do it using a `for` loop. Even as an alternative, `.filter()` isn't a good choice.

Comment: @ Nina Scholz:  I too looked at the reduce implementation, and i have doubt that it would also need the accumulator variable to be created which would be adding to more memory. I will try to test it.

Answer (score 2):

Close! What you need to do is initialize a count variable and then iterate over the array. At each index, you check if the element matches the number. If it does, you increment the count

```js
var v = [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

var count = 0;
var number = 1;

for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
    if (v[i] == number) {
        count++;
    }
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a variety of techniques, but in your case, you need to actually check the array value for 1 as you loop, which you aren't doing.

```js
var v = [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

// Don't assume that there are any occurrences of 1 in the array
count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
  // Test to see if the current array item is 1 and, if so, increment the counter
  
  // The "long-hand" way:
  //if(v[i] === 1){
  //  count++;
  //}
  
  // Above "if" could also be written using JavaScript's "ternary" operator as this:
  count = (v[i] === 1) ? ++count : count;
}

// The report should be after the loop has completed.
console.log ("1 appears in the array " + count + " times.")
```

**Here's another (of many) techniques, but this one removes the loop, the `if` test and the counter completely. It also takes arrays out of the algorithm, which, in turn, can make the code much easier to understand:**

```js
var v = [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

// Turn array into string and (using regular expressions) remove any char that is not 1
var s = v.join("").replace(/[0, 2-9]+/g, "");

// Just check the length of the string after removing non-1 chars:
console.log ("1 appears in the array " + s.length + " times.");
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to increase the count, you are only checking if the count equals what the current item is

```js
var v = [1, 3, 5, 4, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1];

count = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++){
    var cur = v[i];          // < gets the current item
    if (cur == 1)            // < If the current item is 1
        count += 1;          // < Then increase the count by 1
    console.log (count);     // < Log what the count is

}
```