# How to get how many times there is a matching value?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given an array:

```
var nationList = ["Austria", "France", "Austria", "Spain", "Austria"]
```

Given that the following gets the current `svg path` property (I am using [leaflet map](https://leafletjs.com/), so this value is in the `json`).

```
var countryName = e.target.feature.properties.name;
```

I run the following which I found [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389398/finding-out-how-many-times-an-array-element-appears), basically when I mouse hover a polygon, I get countryName and I check how many times is within that array:

```
var fours = nationList.filter(function(it) {return it === countryName;});
var result = fours.length;
```

But if I do: `console.log(result);` it always gives me `1` or `0` if no match.

In the real scenario an example of `console.log(nationList);` gives:

```
["Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan", "Afghanistan",
```

**UDPATE**

What i did before was to try to count each value:

```
  var count = [];
  nationList.sort();
  nationList.forEach(function(i) { 
    var i = i.replace(/^\s+/g, "");
    count[i] = (count[i]||0) + 1;
  });
  console.log(count);
```

That's fine as it gives me for example: `Austria: 22`

But when I do:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  layer.on({
    click: selectNation,
    mouseover: printCount
  });
}

function printCount(e) {
  var countryName = e.target.feature.properties.name;
  var filteredNations = nationList.filter( nation => nation ===countryName);
  var result = filteredNations.length;
  console.log(result);
}
```

Each time I `mouse hover` a `path` with a `property name`, lets say **Austria**, even tho within the `array` we have many repeating occurrences, the `console` gives me `1` if a match is there or `0`

Comment: you should compare the two using the same case. it is possible that one has a different casing (`toUpperCase()` or `toLowerCase()`). also, make sure that full names are being used and not one full and one with the abbreviation.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn it's all fine on that side

Comment: No, it is not. The code youve shown is working

Comment: @JonasW. the case sensitves is fine, if you're saying the code is working, then at the very least should be somewhere else but the cases are fine.

Comment: @rob.m could you at least give us a snippet or fiddle showing exactly how this doesn't work for you, because as you can see from this, it does: http://jsfiddle.net/guywnkpL/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan will try to put one up, thanks

Comment: you could also try to use `e.currentTarget` which is the target that the event is attached to, as opposed to `e.target` which identifies the element on which the event occurred.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn I've updated my question if that helps

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it's a bit complecate to reproduce it, check if the question now updated is of any help

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(countryName)`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yup, that works, gives the correct name

Comment: In that case there's not much help anyone can offer as there's no obvious issues in what you've shown. There must be another underlying problem in your logic.

Comment: resolved, and it was all my fault as I had `$.unique(nationList.sort());` which means it was removing any duplicates...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you have posted seems to be working correctly, but as GetOffMyLawn stated you should compare the two as the same case just to be sure.

```
var nationList = ["Austria", "France", "Austria", "Spain", "Austria"];
var countryName = e.target.feature.properties.name;
var fours = nationList.filter(
  function(it) {
    return it.toLowerCase() === countryName.toLowerCase();
  });
var result = fours.length;

console.log(result);
```

Sorry for the short answer, but not enough reputation at the moment to just post comments.

Comment: Thanks but as I replied to GetOffMyLawn, the cases are fine. matter of fact applying toLowerCase doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Not saying that anything is wrong with the cases, however it is simply best to prepare for the unexpected.  Last thing anyone wants is their code not working one day 5 years from now and no clue why, simple things like this prevent that.  Unless you specifically want say "georgia" and "Georgia" to be different.

Comment: Yes, that actually helps a lot more.  It seems as though you may be referencing the countryName wrong, although I'm not sure.  The code in printCount works, so my only thought is that it must be this line: e.target.feature.properties.name;

Comment: Thought that too, but if I do `console.log(countryName);` works fine.

Comment: Could there be leading or trailing spaces?  Maybe try trimming countryName before your pass it to your filter?

Comment: it was far more lame than that, the code is huge and I had `$.unique(nationList.sort())` somewhere else and missed it. Resolved now. Will accept your answer tho

Comment: Oh ok, glad you were able to locate the problem.