# Lodash remove duplicates from array

Tags: javascript, lodash

This is my data:

```javascript
[
    {
        url: 'www.example.com/hello',
        id: "22"    
    },
    {
        url: 'www.example.com/hello',
        id: "22"    
    },
    {
        url: 'www.example.com/hello-how-are-you',
        id: "23"    
    },
    {
        url: 'www.example.com/i-like-cats',
        id: "24"    
    },
    {
        url: 'www.example.com/i-like-pie',
        id: "25"    
    }
]
```

With Lodash, how could I remove objects with duplicate id keys?
Something with filter, map and unique, but not quite sure.

My real data set is much larger and has more keys, but the concept should be the same.

Answer (score 664, accepted):

`_.unique` no longer works for the current version of Lodash as version 4.0.0 has [this breaking change](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#jan-12-2016--diff--docs). The functionality of `_.unique` was splitted into `_.uniq`, `_.sortedUniq`, `_.sortedUniqBy`, and `_.uniqBy`.

You could use `_.uniqBy` like this:

```
_.uniqBy(data, function (e) {
  return e.id;
});
```

...or like this:

```
_.uniqBy(data, 'id');
```

Documentation: https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy

---

**For older versions of Lodash (< 4.0.0 ):**

Assuming that the data should be uniqued by each object's `id` property and your data is stored in `data` variable, you can use the [`_.unique()`](https://lodash.com/3.10.1#uniq) function like this:

```
_.unique(data, function (e) {
  return e.id;
});
```

Or simply like this:

```
_.uniq(data, 'id');
```

Comment: The lodash 4.0.1 docs have changed this to uniqBy.  Couldn't get the above example to work for the life of me using only uniq.

Comment: With lodash 4.x, uniq() accept only one parameter, which is an array. So as @WillLovett said, we can use uniqBy() to solve this problem.

Comment: Oh boy. Why, oh why, is it `uniq` which is pronounced _you-knee-queue_ instead of what it should be, `unique`...

Answer (score 91):

You could use lodash method _.uniqWith, it is available in the current version of lodash 4.17.2.

Example:

```
var objects = [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }, { 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }];

_.uniqWith(objects, _.isEqual);
// => [{ 'x': 1, 'y': 2 }, { 'x': 2, 'y': 1 }]
```

More info:
https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqWith

Comment: `
let uniqObjects = _.uniqBy(docs, function (e) {
        return e.x + e.y;
});
`
This method will be faster for big arrays with simple objects

Comment: yes but you've to pass an attribute as first argument with uniqBy, which's not convenient if you want it unique based on several attributes that you don't already know

Answer (score 30):

With lodash version 4+, you would remove duplicate objects either by specific property or by the entire object like so:

```
var users = [
  {id:1,name:'ted'},
  {id:1,name:'ted'},
  {id:1,name:'bob'},
  {id:3,name:'sara'}
];
var uniqueUsersByID = _.uniqBy(users,'id'); //removed if had duplicate id
var uniqueUsers = _.uniqWith(users, _.isEqual);//removed complete duplicates
```

Source:https://www.codegrepper.com/?search_term=Lodash+remove+duplicates+from+array

Comment: Was looking for that `var uniqueUsers = _.uniqWith(users, _.isEqual);//removed complete duplicates`

Your anwsers deserves more love

Comment: that's exactly what i was looking for `_.uniqWith(users, _.isEqual)` for unordered object

Answer (score 22):

Or simply Use [union](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#union), for simple array.

```
_.union([1,2,3,3], [3,5])

// [1,2,3,5]
```

Comment: I like this answer. It's not the most readable one, but it actually works if you think about it from a mathematics perspective. `_.union([1, 2, 2, 1, 3]) => [1, 2, 3]`

Comment: clever and concise !!

Answer (score 19):

For a simple array, you have the union approach, but you can also use :

```
_.uniq([2, 1, 2]);
```

Answer (score 10):

Simply use [_.uniqBy()](https://lodash.com/docs/#uniqBy). It creates duplicate-free version of an array.

This is a new way and available from 4.0.0 version.

```
_.uniqBy(data, 'id');
```

or

```
_.uniqBy(data, obj => obj.id);
```

Answer (score 5):

In ***LODASH versions lower than 4*** you will find most of this function are not implemented same way. And opposite from version 4 **_.uniq** was modified. I personally had a project that was in transition for a few months *(from V3 -> to V4)*.

If you run in same situation and you have a lot of functions to be updated. You can do it in stages and when you are done with transition you can come and fix it later. This is the trick i used to avoid downtime of the platform:

```
/* LODASH Version 3 & 4 Compatibility Mode */
if ((_.VERSION).charAt(0) <= 3){ //Detect LODASH version 3 or 4.
    //V3 or lower
    _.uniq(data, true, 'id');
} else {
    //V4 or Higher
    _.uniqBy(data, 'id');
}
```

> Also if you look at lodash documentation for most of this cases you
> can find migration of **_.uniq** from version ***lower than 4*** can be performed
> with both functions:
>
> **_.uniqBy(data, 'id')** or
> **_.unionBy(data, 'id')**
>
> Both of them will bring same result. I personally was guessing which
> one to pick. In the end I picked this one:  **_.uniqBy(data, 'id')**.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [unionBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#unionBy) for 4.0.0 and later, as follows:
let uniques = _.unionBy(data, 'id')