# using lodash unique on an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am not sure how to use this to remove duplicate arrays from the main array. so consider the following:

```
var arr = [
    [0, 1],
    [0, 1],
    [2, 1],
];
```

The resulting array should look like:

```
var arr = [
    [0, 1],
    [2, 1],
];
```

The documentation makes sense for a single array of elements but not a 2d array.

**Ideas?**

### Update, One small issue with some solutions:

The array to be turned unique might have:

```
var arr = [
  [0, 1]
  [0, 2]
  [0, 3]
  [0, 1]
  [2, 1]
]
```

the array in side the array should have all value compared, so in the above example, it should spit out:

```
var arr = [
  [0, 1]
  [0, 2]
  [0, 3]
  [2, 1]
]
```

The duplicate being `[0, 1]`

Comment: [What](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) [have](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [you tried](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Will this help: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740155/lodash-remove-duplicates-from-array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740155/lodash-remove-duplicates-from-array)

Comment: @user2174714 Not exactly, Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would probably be to use `uniq` method and then convert the inner arrays to some string representation, `JSON.stringify` should be good enough solution.

```
var arr = [[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 1], [2, 1]]
_.uniq(arr, function(item) { 
    return JSON.stringify(item); 
});
// [[0,1], [0,2], [0,3], [2,1]]
```

Comment: Do you have example of what this would spit out?

Comment: As of Lodash v4.0.0, you have to use `_.uniqBy` instead

Answer (score 3):

You would use the `.uniq` function in `lodash`:

```
var arr = [
    [0, 1],
    [0, 1],
    [2, 1],
]

var uniqueList = _.uniq(arr, function(item, key, a) { 
    return item.a;
});
```

The resulting array will look like:

```
//var arr = [Object: [0, 1], Object: [2, 1]];
```

Comment: I update my question with a small hitch that I caught when testing your concept. Could you take a look and see if yuor solution can be tweaked to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, casting to JSON works, but it feels like we might be wasting resources. I'm using the following Lodash-code in Node.js:

```
const _ = require("lodash");

var arr = [
    [0, 1],
    [0, 1],
    [2, 1],
];

var uni = _.uniqWith(arr, _.isEqual);
console.log(uni);
```

Works like a charm, [check the Repl here](https://repl.it/@keestalkstech/ToughPleasedApplications#index.js). More on [uniqWith at the Lodash docs](https://lodash.com/docs/latest#uniqWith).

Comment: Not sure why this answer had been voted down. It works beautifully.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't use lodash, not optimized I agree :

```
//remove duplicate array of array of arrays
Array.prototype.uniqueArray = function() {
    var uniqObj = {};
    this.forEach(function (item) {
        uniqObj[JSON.stringify(item)] = 1;
    });

    var uniqArray = [];
    for(var key in uniqObj) {
        if (uniqObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            uniqArray.push(JSON.parse(key))
        }
    }
    return uniqArray;
};
```