# get uniq [key,value] from object array with lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, lodash

I have an object array, products, with properties "categoryid, categoryname, name, price".
I want to return an object array with just "categoryid, categoryname" from this but since categoryid exist multiple times, I want only the unique results.

I can get both fields with this code but it won't be unique.

```
_.map(products, _.partialRight(_.pick, ['categoryid', 'category']))
```

How can I make this unique?

Comment: Would you be okay with JS only solution or Lodash is a must?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740155/lodash-remove-duplicates-from-array

Comment: As @gurvinder372 mentioned you can get the unique values first and then map them out. `_(products).uniqBy('categoryId').map(_.partialRight(_.pick, ['categoryid', 'categroyname'])).value()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could do it in two separate lines:

```
var uniq = _.uniqBy(vm.productList, 'categoryid');
vm.categories = _.map(uniq, _.partialRight(_.pick, ['categoryid', 'category']))
```