# JS - Duplicate Elements in the Array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Okay i can't explain what i'm trying to do . but i can explain whit code.

i have this array :

```
var array = [{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"},{name:"Alex",lastname:"Bill"},{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"}]
```

the array contains 2 elements duplicated , I want a function that shows me only once an element duplicate

when you apply the function this will be the result of the array

```
var array = [{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"},{name:"Alex",lastname:"Bill"}]
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/31740263/1214800

Comment: You are looking for a deep compare.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove Duplicates from JavaScript Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it with javascript [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function in old fashioned way.

```
var array = [{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"},{name:"Alex",lastname:"Bill"},{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"}]
var names = [];

array = array.filter(function (person) {
   var fn = person.name + '-' + person.lastname;
   if (names.indexOf(fn) !== -1) {
      return false;
   }
   else {
      names.push(fn);
      return true;
   }
});

console.log(array); 
// [{"name":"John","lastname":"Doe"},{"name":"Alex","lastname":"Bill"}]
```

Answer (score 0):

you use lodash library which gives you many array/object & string functions.

```
var array = [{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"},{name:"Alex",lastname:"Bill"},{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"}]

_.uniqWith(array, _.isEqual);//[{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"},{name:"Alex",lastname:"Bill"}]
```

The above code will check deep equality of each object and create a unique array.

Docs : [lodash uniqWith](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqWith)

Comment: Lodash and underscore are different libraries.

Comment: @zerkms Thanks for your input. I thought both are different only by name but does the same job with reference to functionality.

Answer (score 0):

the very simple way is use the underscore

```
var array = [{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"},{name:"Alex",lastname:"Bill"},{name:"John",lastname:"Doe"}]  

array  = _.uniq(array , false, function(p) {
                 return p.name;
            });
```

use the unique to achive