# Lodash Map only on a Condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, lodash

I have a file called events.json which I require then use .map to create my object,

```
var data = require('./events.json')
var newEventList = data.events.map(events => ({
    id: events.id ,
    name: events.name ,
    venue: events.venue.name
}));
```

However, sometimes on occasion I get two event.ids which are identical. In these instances the map method creates a duplicate entry in my newEventList object. Can I set a conditional within the map function to skip the 'mapping' of that entry if the ids are identical?

One thing to add is that the duplicates always are consecutive in the events.json so the If statement would only be comparing the previously mapped item.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why dont you filter the `data.events` first , before mapping , say using `_.unique()` ?

Comment: I've never heard of this method before. Thanks I will take a look.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740155/lodash-remove-duplicates-from-array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `_.uniqBy` available in  lodash (Assuming OP wants a `loadash` solution)

```
 var data = require('./events.json');
 var _ = require('lodash')
 var newEventList = _.uniqBy(data.events,'id').map(events => ({
     id: events.id ,
     name: events.name ,
    venue: events.venue.name  
 }));
```

Comment: 2 very similar answers here but am going to take this one as I like the way it is all contained in one function. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using `lodash`,  you can use the `_.uniqBy` function that lets you remove duplicates in an array :

```
const data = require('./events.json');
const uniqEvents = _.uniqBy(data.events, 'id');
const newEventList = uniqEvents.map(events => 
   id: events.id ,
   name: events.name ,
   venue: events.venue.name
);
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) creates an output for every item in the original array, so you can't skip items. You can use [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead with a helper `dedupe` [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). For each item, check if the `id` is in the Set. If not, add it to the result array, and to the Set.

```
const data = require('./events.json')
const dedupe = new Set();
const newEventList = data.events.reduce((list, event) => {
  if(!dedupe.has(event.id)) {
    list.push({
      id: event.id ,
      name: event.name ,
      venue: event.venue.name
    });

    dedupe.add(event.id);
  }

  return list;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var idList = [];
var data = require('./events.json')
var newEventList = data.events.map(events => {
idList.indexOf(events.id) !== -1 return // If id exists, skip
idList.push(events.id); // Else push in list for comparing 
return { // And add obj to array
    id: events.id ,
    name: events.name ,
    venue: events.venue.name
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for a non-lodash answer too!