# Remove duplicate substring in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like below:

```
[
  'author/2020/01/01/all_authors_000.csv',
  'book/2020/01/01/all_books_000.csv',
  'book/2020/01/01/all_books_001.csv',
  'book/2020/01/01/all_books_002.csv',
  'others/2020/01/01/other_stuff.csv',
]
```

As you can see there are three items that start with the word `book`.  I want to remove all but one, so I end up with something like:

```
[
  'author/2020/01/01/all_authors_000.csv',
  'book/2020/01/01/all_books_000.csv',
  'others/2020/01/01/other_stuff.csv',
]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Technically your question says ***Remove duplicate substring in an array*** and there is no duplicate.

Comment: The substring `book/` is being duplicated

Comment: what is the criteria. are `book/2020` and `book/2021` also dublicates?

Comment: No, just the word `book`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is working example:

```js
var array = [
   "author/2020/01/01/all_authors_000.csv",
   "book/2020/01/01/all_books_000.csv",
   "book/2020/01/01/all_books_001.csv",
   "book/2020/01/01/all_books_002.csv",
   "others/2020/01/01/other_stuff.csv",
];

var filteredArray = [];
var previous = "";

for (let i of array) {
   if (i.substr(0, i.indexOf("/")) != previous) {
      filteredArray.push(i);
      previous = i.substr(0, i.indexOf("/"));
   }
}
```

Every loop the value before `"/2020"` is stored inside the `previous` variable, and the if statement checks, if the value is the same as in the previous loop. If not, it pushes it into the `filteredArray`.

Therefore `filteredArray` is the array without duplicates.

Comment: thank you. do you know if this can also be achieved by lodash?

Comment: @blankface I don't have experience with lodash myself, but take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740155/lodash-remove-duplicates-from-array).

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method of doing it. Basically a function that takes in your array and a criteria to identify duplicates (in your case `book`). All of these duplicates will be removed but the first one.

```js
const array = [
  "author/2020/01/01/all_authors_000.csv",
  "book/2020/01/01/all_books_000.csv",
  "book/2020/01/01/all_books_001.csv",
  "book/2020/01/01/all_books_002.csv",
  "others/2020/01/01/other_stuff.csv",
];

const removeDuplicates = (array, criteria) => {
  return array.filter(
    (path) =>
      ![...array.filter((path) => path.includes(criteria)).splice(1)].includes(
        path
      )
  );
};

console.log(removeDuplicates(array, "book"));
```