# Remove duplicate objects from an Array

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an Array with duplicate objects, and I want to remove those duplicate objects. But I can't seem to find a proper solution for it. What is my mistake over here?

The object is as below.

```
{name: "login", text: "Login"}
{name: "navigation", text: "Navigation"}
{name: "landing", text: "Landing Page"}
{name: "login", text: "Login"}
{name: "navigation", text: "Navigation"}
{name: "landing", text: "Landing Page"}
```

Below is my code where `items` has the array of objects.

```
this.subMenuItems = this.items.reduce((acc, current) => {
  const x = acc.find(item => item.name === current.name);
  if (!x) {
    return acc.concat([current]);
  } else {
    return acc;
  }
}, []);
```

Also you can refer the screenshot of the Console.log of the `items` variable
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove all duplicates from an array of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218999/how-to-remove-all-duplicates-from-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: I tried this exact same code in the browser console and it works perfectly fine. Can you share some more code from your Angular component, since I believe that the issue is to be found somewhere else

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel. Have a look at lodash uniqBy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740155/lodash-remove-duplicates-from-array

You can specifically install lodash.uniqBy instead of importing the whole lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.uniqby

That way to achieve your desired output with a very well tested code which probably has more capabilities.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, some help from that and some help from this question got me a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one will assign `this.subMenuItems` an array containing only the first instance of each item because `indexOf` returns the first index where the object is found.

```
this.subMenuItems = this.items.filter((item, index, self) => self.indexOf(item) === index);
```

Comment: Please also consider giving the explanation about the cause of the problem in the OP's code.

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

The problem with your code is that `find` will always return a defined value because there is atleast one object satisfying the condition (`current` object itself)

### Solution

One solution is the solution which @Issac gave. It's time and space complexities are `O(n^2)` and `O(1)` resp.

There is one more solution with time and space complexities `O(n)` and `O(n)` resp.

```js
function removeDuplicates(objects) {
  const map = new Map()

  for (const obj of objects) {
    map.put(obj.name, obj)
  }

  return map.values()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please find below a function that can return the list of duplicates or a list that removes duplicates.

```
identifyDuplicates(data: Object[], key: string, unique: boolean = 
true) {
    const unique: Object[] = [];
    const duplicates = data.filter(x => {
        if (unique.length > 0 && (unique?.find(u => u[key] == x[key]) != null)) 
    {  return true; }
        unique.push(x);
        return false;
    });
    return unique ? unique : duplicates;
}
```

it can be called in two ways:

```
public getUnique(data: Object[], key: string) {
    return this.identifyDuplicates(data, key);
}

public getDuplicate(data: Object[], key: string) {
    return this.identifyDuplicates(data, key, false);
}
```

for your case:

```
const unique = this.getUnique(this.subMenuItems, 'name');
console.log(JSON.stringify(unique ));
```

if you want to get the duplicate items

```
const duplicates = this.getDuplicate(this.subMenuItems, 'name');
console.log(JSON.stringify(duplicates));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function solve(items) {
    var m = {}
    items.forEach((obj) => {
        var name = obj.name;
        var text = obj.text;
        if (!m[name]) {
            m[name] = new Set();
        }
        m[name].add(text);

    });
    var finalItemsList = [];
    Object.keys(m).forEach((name) => {
        Array.from(m[name]).forEach((text) => {
            finalItemsList.push({
                "name": name,
                "text": text
            })
        });

    });
    return finalItemsList;

}
console.log(items);
```

Comment: It's rather a long code. Please consirder adding some commenta to the code so that its easier for OP to integrate it in their code.

Comment: Not a big fan of descriptive function names are you?

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the efforts to help me, however this solution didn't work for me. but Kudos to you for making your best effort  to help

Comment: @oni3619, thanks man!!, can I know the test data for which the code had failed.