# how to exclude some elements from javascript Array.map() callback

Tags: javascript, arrays

Essentially, I want to implement the following:

```
var categories = [];
var products = // some array of product objects
products.map(function(value) {
   if(categories.indexOf(value.Category === -1)) categories.push(value.Category);
});
```

As result, `categories` array contains unique list of product categories.

I *feel* that there should be a better way to do it, but nothing comes to mind.

If there *isn't* then probably there is no point to use `map()` in the first place. I could do as simple as

```
var categories = [];
var products = // some array of product objects
for (var i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
   if(categories.indexOf(products[i].Category === -1)) categories.push(products[i].Category);
}
```

UPDATE for those who insist it's a duplicate of "how to make an array unique" question. I saw that post, and for my situation I don't think it applies. I **don't** have an array of values that I need to make unique. I have an array of objects and I need to **build** an array of unique values. The difference might be subtle - but to get to the use case of that topic I would build a non-unique array and then make it unique. Seems even worse than my original solution

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1960473/unique-values-in-an-array)

Comment: please add some sample data.

Comment: i'm with @NinaScholz

Comment: i think, you misuse `map` for simply iterating. the right method is `forEach`.

Comment: Then Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Comment: @NinaScholz - I think you are correct. I started with an assumption that map() will give me the ability to filter out as it goes; but if it doesn't than for or forEach is the way to go. Thanks

Comment: Seriously?! Downvoting the question *and* downvoting first correct answer?! Alright then...

Comment: @Felix, if you or Bex had checked that answer you approved you'd see there's an error in it.

Comment: @Andy - the value of Bek's answer is pointing out that I can use reduce() to build an array; as opposed to generating a scalar. There were some edits in Bek's answer; so maybe the error was fixed - or maybe I got the idea and implemented it correctly. In any event, it works fine!

Comment: @Felix But it has no value as an answer to anyone else coming to this question in months/years time if it's full of errors.

Comment: Andy - somebody else will have somewhat different situation. In fact, my real situation didn't deal with products and categories, either. I tried to simplify the question by removing irrelevant stuff (didn't help me much - still got downvoted for some unclear reason - but hey, it's life). Bek's answer got me in the right direction - and I thank him for that. I wish I could accept @NinaScholz answer as well. In any event, Bek made the correction. Let's all be a little nicer to each other - it's Christmas, after all! :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

you can use `reduce` instead of `map`

```
var products = [{Category:'vegetable', price: 1}, {Category:'fruits', price: 2}];
var categories = products.reduce(function(sum, product) {
 if(sum.indexOf(product.Category) === -1){
  sum.push(product.Category);
 }
 return sum;
}, []);
```

Comment: reduce will give me a single value (eg., sum). I need array of values (eg., Categories)

Comment: It is not a single value it is array where things getting accumulated

Comment: Wow! Haven't thought of using reduce in this manner! Marking as answer

Comment: it rewrites product. categories is not defined. the whole object is pushed. indexof does not work on objects.

Comment: @NinaScholz - yes, should be pushing product.Category, of course!

Comment: my point was to show how `reduce` could be used not solving specific problem anyways fixed it

Answer (score 6):

Update: A solution with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var products = [{ Name: 'milk', price: 2.50, Category: 'groceries' }, { Name: 'shirt', price: 10, Category: 'clothing' }, { Name: 'apples', price: 5, Category: 'groceries' }],
    categories = products.reduce(function (r, a) {
        if (!~r.indexOf(a.Category)) {
            r.push(a.Category);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(categories, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I don't think this will work - within `filter` categories is always an empty array, and comparison will **always** return true. Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: please supply some example data, the it's more likely to see what you want.

Comment: @Felix this answer shows how to implement what question asking (filter values in functional style vs. imperative), but it is not what you actually need and duplicate Vankat found answers it perfectly.

Comment: Products = [{Name: 'milk', price: 2.50, Category: 'groceries'}, {Name: 'shirt', price: 10, Category: 'clothing'}, {Name: 'apples', price: 5, Category: 'groceries'}] Expected result: Categories = ['groceries', 'clothing']

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I was looking for. In fairness @Bek answered first.

Comment: @Felix, in future, perhaps don't think of it as a race. Bex might have answered first wrt `reduce` but the answer was very poor/not checked.

Answer (score 3):

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) all the values of the object categories out first, then use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to dispose of the duplicates.

```
var products = [
  { category: 'A' },
  { category: 'B' },
  { category: 'A' },
  { category: 'D' }
];

var categories = products.map(function (e) {
  return e.category;
}).filter(function (e, i, a) {
  return a.indexOf(e) === i;
}); // [ "A", "B", "D" ]
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dumt9gg9/)

Comment: @NinaScholz, does it say somewhere that indexOf was to be avoided?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the Below SO Answer:

[How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

```
var flags = [], output = [], l = array.length, i;
for( i=0; i<l; i++) {
    if( flags[array[i].age]) continue;
    flags[array[i].age] = true;
    output.push(array[i].age);
}
```