# Array truncation with splice method

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to delete occurrences of an element if it occurs more than n times.

For example, there is this array:

```
[20,37,20,21]
```

And the output should be:

```
[20,37,21]
```

I thought one way of solving this could be with the splice method

First I sort the array it order to make it like this:

```
[20,20,37,21]
```

Then I check if the current element is not equal to the next and split the array into chunks, so it should look like:

```
[20, 20],[37],[21]
```

Later I can edit the chunk longer than 1 and join it all again.

This is what the code looks like in my head but didn't work in real life

```
var array = [20, 37, 20, 21];
var chunk = [];
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if(array[i] !== array[i + 1]) {
        var index = array.indexOf(array[i]);
        chunk.push = array.splice(0, index) // cut from zero to last duplicate element
    } else
        var index2 = a.indexOf(a[i]);
    chunk.push(a.splice(0, index));
}
```

with this code the output is

```
[[], [20, 20]]
```

I think It's something in the `'else'` but can't figure it out what to fix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15125920/1026459)

Answer (score 0):

As the logic you want to achieve is to delete `n` occurrences of element in an `array`, your code could be as follow:

```
var array = [1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2];
var n = 2;

var removeMultipleOccurences = function(array, n) {
  var filteredArray = [];
  var counts = {};
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    var x = array[i];
    counts[x] = counts[x] ? counts[x] + 1 : 1;
    if (counts[x] <= n) filteredArray.push(array[i])
  }
  return filteredArray;
}

console.log(removeMultipleOccurences(array, n));
```

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain it good. If the array is [20, 20, 20, 20, 21,21, 37] and 'n' is 3 it should be [20,20,20,21,21,37]. I don't see how filter can work in this case

Comment: @cetaphil If you are trying to remove element at index 3 a loop is not necessary. You can use `var array = [20, 20, 20, 20, 21,21, 37]; array.splice(n, 1)`, where n is `3`

Comment: 'n' should be the number of times a item can repeat itself, I need the loop to look for duplicates items in the whole array. If I use it as index at 3 something like this would happen  [1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2,2] => [1, 1, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2, 2]. In this case '2' repeat more than 'n' times.

Comment: @cetaphil Please check the edited code snipped to meet your needed logic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()`, `Array.prototype.filter()` to check if `n` previous elements are the same as current element

```js
let cull = (arr, n) => arr.reduce((res, curr) => [...res
           , res.filter(v => v === curr).length === n 
           ? !1 : curr].filter(Boolean), []);

let arrays = [[20,37,20,21], [1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2,2]];
              
let cullone = cull(arrays[0], 1);

let cullthree = cull(arrays[1], 3);

console.log(cullone // [20, 37, 21]
            , cullthree // [1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2]
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this one, based on array filter checking repeated values up to a limit, but I can see @Basim's function does the same.

```
function removeDuplicatesAbove(arr, max) {
    if (max > arr.length) {max = arr.length;}
    if (!max) {return arr;}
    return arr.filter(function (v, i) {
        var under = true, base = -1;
        for (var n = 0; n < max; n++) {
            base = arr.indexOf(v, base+1); if (base == -1) {break;}
        }
        if (base != -1 && base < i) {under = false;}
        return under;
    });
}

var exampleArray = [20, 37, 20, 20, 20, 37, 22, 37, 20, 21, 37];

console.log(removeDuplicatesAbove(exampleArray, 3)); // [20, 37, 20, 20, 37, 22, 37, 21]
```

Answer (score 0):

Always when you use `splice()` you **truncate** the array. Truncate the array with the *length* of **same** **values** from the start with the help of `lastIndexOf()`. It always starts from `0`.

```
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 ] // splice(0, 3)
[ 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5 ] // splice(0, 3)
[ 3, 4, 4, 5 ] // splice(0, 1)
[ 4, 4, 5 ] // splice(0, 2)
[ 5 ] // splice(0, 1)
```

Do this as long as the array length is greater than `0`.

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5];
var res = [];

while (arr.length > 0) {
  var n = arr[0];
  var last = arr.lastIndexOf(n) + 1;
  res.push(n);
  arr.splice(0, last);
}

console.log(res);
```