# How to count number of occurrences of distinct values from an array of objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like below:

```
var array =
    [
        {"name":"abc","age":20}
        {"name":"abc","age":20}
        {"name":"abc","age":20}
        {"name":"xyz","age":21}
        {"name":"xyz","age":21}
    ]
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of distinct values like:

```
[3,2]
```

Assuming `abc` has 3 occurrences and `xyz` has 2 occurrences.

I am doing it in `reactjs`. I am able to get distinct values like `[abc,xyz]` using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/35092559#35092559).

<sub>ES6 syntax is preferred.</sub>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You'll need to know to which name a count belongs, so I propose not to output an array that gives you no clue about that, but an object keyed by names and with as value the corresponding count:

```
var result = array.reduce( (acc, o) => (acc[o.name] = (acc[o.name] || 0)+1, acc), {} );
```

```js
var array =
    [
        {"name":"abc","age":20},
        {"name":"abc","age":20},
        {"name":"abc","age":20},
        {"name":"xyz","age":21},
        {"name":"xyz","age":21}
    ];
    
var result = array.reduce( (acc, o) => (acc[o.name] = (acc[o.name] || 0)+1, acc), {} );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 7):

Map/Reduce to the rescue:

```
const frequency = array
  .map(({ name }) => name)
  .reduce((names, name) => {
    const count = names[name] || 0;
    names[name] = count + 1;
    return names;
  }, {});

// frequency: { abc: 3, xyz: 2 }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `forEach/map` to iterate the array and store the count in another variable, Check this:

```js
var array = [
     {"name" : "abc", "age" : 20},
     {"name" : "abc", "age" : 20},
     {"name" : "abc", "age" : 20},
     {"name" : "xyz", "age" : 21},
     {"name" : "xyz", "age" : 21},
];
    
let b = {};

array.forEach(el => {
    b[el.name] = (b[el.name] || 0) + 1;
})

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Still if anyone looking for distinct counts stored in an array

```
var result = array.reduce( (acc, o) => (acc[o.name] = (acc[o.name] || 0)+1, acc), {} );
result = Object.values(result); // returns an array of values from the object
// result will be [3,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it:

```js
var array =
 [
  {"name":"abc","age":20},
  {"name":"abc","age":20},
  {"name":"abc","age":20},
  {"name":"xyz","age":21},
  {"name":"xyz","age":21}
 ]


let yy = {}
array.map( el => {
 yy[el.name] = (yy[el.name] || 0) + 1
})

console.log(yy)
```

And this is another way:

```js
var array =
 [
  {"name":"abc","age":20},
  {"name":"abc","age":20},
  {"name":"abc","age":20},
  {"name":"xyz","age":21},
  {"name":"xyz","age":21}
 ]


let yy = {}
array.map( el => {
 if (yy[el.name] === undefined || yy[el.name] === 0) {
  yy[el.name] = 1
 } else {
  yy[el.name] = yy[el.name] + 1
 }
})

console.log(yy)
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick answer : `new Set(array).size`.

Explanation (From MDN Web Docs):

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references

Comment: That will just return the length of the array. That is not what the asker wants.

Comment: @trincot Nope. It will retrun the cardianality of the Set, which contains unique elements.

Comment: I think you misinterpreted the question: the size of the Set will be the same as the length of the Array as all objects in the OP's array are distinct. You would only get a difference if some objects were referenced multiple times in that array, but that is not so for what the OP presents: their question is not to look for unique object references, but for objects that have a unique property value (i.e.  `name`) in those *distinct* objects.