# lodash get an array of element grouped by a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, lodash

I have a JSON array returned by an API call

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aa",
    "zone": 1

}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "bb",
    "zone": 1

}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "cc",
    "zone": 2

}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "dd",
    "zone": 2
}
]
```

By using lodash I did `_.groupBy(myData,'zone')` and the result was an Object containing 2 arrays, each one for a different zone.
But what I need to achieve, in an object containing an array of zones and for each zone an array of associated names.

Desired result:

```
[
   {
      "zone": "1",
      "items": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "aa",
            "zone": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bb",
            "zone": 1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "zone": "2",
      "items": [
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "cc",
            "zone": 2
         },
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "dd",
            "zone": 2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Is possible to transform the original array into the one I need using lodash?
Later on my Angular template I want to do an `*ngFor='let zone of zones'` or something similar

Comment: What do you expect the end result to look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @Whymarrh I edited the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming you did this :

```
result = _.groupBy(myData,'zone')
```

just add this **after** **the** **lodash** function:

```
result = Object.keys(result).map(key => ({ zone: key, items: result[key] }));
```

And you'll get this :

```
 [
   {
      "zone": "1",
      "items": [
         {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "aa",
            "zone": 1
         },
         {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "bb",
            "zone": 1
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "zone": "2",
      "items": [
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "cc",
            "zone": 2
         },
         {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "dd",
            "zone": 2
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
let zones = _.chain(_.groupBy(myData, 'zone')).map(function (val, key) {
    return {
        zone: key,
        names: _.map(val, "name") // Assuming you only need names. You can have the whole object too if needed
    };
}).value();
```

This will produce:

```
[
    {
        "zone": "1",
        "names": ["aa", "bb"]
    },
    {
        "zone": "2",
        "names": ["cc", "dd"]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to create a JSON object with some keys with **zone** values and the corresponding **names** as an array assigned to that key,
you can use **`reduce`** function of lodash. Simply do:

```
_.reduce(myData, function(result, value, key) {
    (result[value.zone] || (result[value.zone] = [])).push(value.name);
    return result;
  }, {});
```

The code will produce:

```
{"1":["aa","bb"],"2":["cc","dd"]}
```

```js
var myData = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "aa",
  "zone": 1

}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "bb",
  "zone": 1

}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "cc",
  "zone": 2

}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "dd",
  "zone": 2
}];

console.log(JSON.stringify(
  _.reduce(myData, function(result, value, key) {
    (result[value.zone] || (result[value.zone] = [])).push(value.name);
    return result;
  }, {})
));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Here you can find the lodash documentaion for `reduce`:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce

Answer (score 0):

Below is my implementation of what you want, although without Lodash (at least what I think it is you want. The result is an array of arrays, each inner array containing each original object of a particular zone).

```js
let originalArray = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "aa",
    "zone": 1

}, {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "bb",
    "zone": 1

}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "cc",
    "zone": 2

}, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "dd",
    "zone": 2
}]

let transitionObject = {};

for (let i = 0; i < originalArray.length; i++) {
  let currentObject = originalArray[i];
  transitionObject[currentObject.zone] = transitionObject[currentObject.zone] || { names: []};
  transitionObject[currentObject.zone].names.push(currentObject.name);
}

console.log(transitionObject);
```