# Ng-table select filtering issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

I am trying to filter the ng-table data with select drop down, the issue is select dropdown the values are not populating and ofcos filtering doesn't work, i am using ng-table 2.1.0 version. i tried changing the $scope.names object to hardcoded object i.e., `$scope.names=[{title:'Moroni'},{title:'Enos'},{title:'Jacob'}];` then values are populating in select dropdown i am assuming there must be property 'title' for every object, but still filtering doesn't work either, is there anything missing here? plunker [`Here`](https://plnkr.co/edit/JXKgQTRMJYyIsgoaeewu?p=preview)

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see from the expression in [`ngOptions`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) attribute:

```
ng-options="data.id as data.title for data in $selectData"
```

The format of the option should be `{id: ..., title: ...}`. So I think you can change your `angular.forEach` block with something like this:

```
  var titles = data.map(function(obj) { return obj.title; });
  $scope.names = titles.filter(function(title, i) { return titles.indexOf(title) === i; })
                       .map(function(title) { return {title: title, id: title}; });
```

This is not the fastest method to generate this array (added this just to illustrate the structure). More performant ways to do this [could be found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript).

[Working fiddle.](https://plnkr.co/edit/j7NYQU97b11ANDgqldH8?p=preview)

Comment: How did i miss to check in DOM for the ngOptions format, thank you very much for pointing it out.