# Get the distinct object from the array of objects in Typescript Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

I have an array of object as shown below:

```
[{
    "name": "Okta Verify Push",
    "provider": "OKTA",
    "type": "push",
    "status": 0,
    "id": "opfhgfgaidhyBw2H90h7"
}, {
    "name": "Okta Verify TOTP",
    "provider": "OKTA",
    "type": "token:software:totp",
    "status": 0,
    "id": "osthgek5jmWTckcka0h7"
}, {
    "name": "Unknown",
    "provider": "CUSTOM",
    "type": "claims_provider",
    "status": 1,
    "id": "clpn4wdtqtH6geILD0h7"
}, {
    "name": "Google Authenticator",
    "provider": "GOOGLE",
    "type": "token:software:totp",
    "status": 1,
    "id": null
}]
```

I want to get the distinct object as array based on the `**provider**`

I tried

`[...new Set(item.filter(factor => factor.status == MultiFactorAuthenticationEnrolmentStatus.Enrolled).map(factor => factor.provider))];`

This returns string of array such as ["GOOGLE", "OKTA","CUSTOM"]

My requirement is to get the Array of Object such as

```
[{
    "name": "Okta Verify Push",
    "provider": "OKTA",
    "type": "push",
    "status": 0,
    "id": "opfhgfgaidhyBw2H90h7"
},  {
    "name": "Unknown",
    "provider": "CUSTOM",
    "type": "claims_provider",
    "status": 1,
    "id": "clpn4wdtqtH6geILD0h7"
}, {
    "name": "Google Authenticator",
    "provider": "GOOGLE",
    "type": "token:software:totp",
    "status": 1,
    "id": null
}]
```

Reference - [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: How would you know to take `"Okta Verify Push"` over `"Okta Verify TOTP"`? Does the order count?

Comment: @woat Yes I need to take the first item, in this case - "Okta Verify Push"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case that you have a preference for taking the first occurrence, you can first map the data into an object based on `provider` being the `key` and itself as the `value`. Once that is done, you can then extract the all of the values with `Object#values`.

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "Okta Verify Push",
    "provider": "OKTA",
    "type": "push",
    "status": 0,
    "id": "opfhgfgaidhyBw2H90h7"
}, {
    "name": "Okta Verify TOTP",
    "provider": "OKTA",
    "type": "token:software:totp",
    "status": 0,
    "id": "osthgek5jmWTckcka0h7"
}, {
    "name": "Unknown",
    "provider": "CUSTOM",
    "type": "claims_provider",
    "status": 1,
    "id": "clpn4wdtqtH6geILD0h7"
}, {
    "name": "Google Authenticator",
    "provider": "GOOGLE",
    "type": "token:software:totp",
    "status": 1,
    "id": null
}]


const values = Object.values(
  data.reduce((a, b) => {
    if (!a[b.provider]) a[b.provider] = b 
      return a
   }, {})
)

console.log(values)
```