# Filtering Javascript object Array by existing array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to filter this large dataset down and I've run into a problem.vI'm using the MovieLens uesr ratings dataset and cut it down to about 10000 entries and removed the timestamp column.

The data is stored like ["userId":1,"movieId":1,"rating":1] and I have an array of duplicate values that are most commonly coming up. I want to remove all elements that don't match one of the 8 values in the duplicate list dupList. I don't really use filters that often and I've tried this but it didnt work.

```
var filtered = movieDataArray.filter(
    function(e) {
        // console.log(e);
        return this.indexOf(e.movieId) < 0;
    },
    dupList
);
```

I've also tried a few lodash functions, intersect, union, etc. in the vain hope that one of them would work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Since you want only those values in the `filtered` list which have `e.movieId` present in `dupList` list and rest should not be included in the `filtered` list, then you need to change your code a little bit.

Correct implementation:

```js
var filtered = movieDataArray.filter(
    function(e) {
        return this.indexOf(e.movieId) >= 0;
    },
    dupList
);
```