# Fast way to get unique attribute list from object list

Tags: javascript, arrays, set

I have an object list with a large number of elements of `Test`:

```
Test:{name:'', creator:''}
```

Require to extract a **unique** creators list from that list. I have tried:

```
const creators = Array.from(new Set(tests.map(t=>t.creator))
```

This works fine but, due to rapid changes, I have to call this again and again. So, this takes more time and lags the UI. How to build this array more efficiently than the current implementation?

**EDIT:**

Context information:

Require unique element array(**not set**) due to rendering on UI by

`tests.map(test=><Test data={test}/>)`

Comment: Why do you convert the set to an array? Just use the set, and update the set when a change to the data occurs.

Comment: I have to call map on that array for rendering purpose

Comment: this cannot be answered efficiently without context, please provide more informations.

Comment: you can probably simply cache the `Set` or use some kind of `Multimap` or this isn't really the bottleneck at all.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: You can iterate a set as well.

Answer (score -2):

You can use lodash library's function "uniqBy" to overcome this issue.

Documentation: https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy

Example:-

```
_.uniqBy(data, function (e) {
  return e.creator;
});
```