# Spread operator over an array of objects in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to use `spread operator` to find a unique set on this

```js
let obj = {
  requests: [{
      id: 'p1',
      isOptional: false,
      item: [Object]
    },
    {
      id: 'p1',
      isOptional: false,
      item: [Object]
    }
  ]
};

// I tried below.
let output = [...new Set(obj.requests)];
console.log(output);
```

But that did not work.

Comment: The data is already unique...

Comment: Could you please add what's the expected result?

Comment: I updated the request.

Comment: What uniquely identifies an item in your `requests` array? The `id`? All properties?

Comment: Yes its the id that recognizes.

Comment: And if there's a duplicate `id`, which item should be the one kept? The first encountered, or the last?

Comment: What's the obsession with spread syntax here? To directly answer your question of _"Can it be done using spread operator"_, the answer is **no**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this either by using `filter` or `spread Operator` with `map`. Just using a spread operator with `new Set` will not give the desired results.

Using [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var data = {
  requests: [{
      id: 'p1',
      isOptional: false,
      item: [Object]
    },
    {
      id: 'p1',
      isOptional: false,
      item: [Object]
    }
  ]
}

var unique = data.requests.filter(function({id}) {
  return !this[id] && (this[id] = id)
}, {})

console.log(unique )
```

Using [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

```js
var data = {
  requests: [{
      id: 'p1',
      isOptional: false,
      item: [Object]
    },
    {
      id: 'p1',
      isOptional: false,
      item: [Object]
    }
  ]
}

var unique = [...new Set(data.requests.map(({id}) => id))].map(e => data.requests.find(({id}) => id == e)); 

console.log(unique )
```

Comment: Yes this works well but i wanted to use spread operator here.

Comment: @Prakhar Not just with spread operator - you have use map with that. Check now. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

You may get your answer to your question from here [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript). **Below is explanation why it didn't work as you have expected.**

You can not find `unique` `objects` with using `Set` unless they both `object` are having `same` reference. So in your case it seems you are having two different `references` for both `objects` inside array. Thus `Set` will return `2` `values`.

If you are having `same` `reference` for both `objects` *(for eg. let o = {id: 'p1',isOptional: false,item: [Object]}) and let obj = {requests: [o,o]}* then it will return unique values.

You can verify the same at [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as below screenshot.
[image]

Consider below sample.

```js
let o = {
  id: 'p1',
  isOptional: false,
  item: {
    id: 10
  }
};

let obj = {
  requests: [o, o]
}

let output = [...new Set(obj.requests)];
console.log('Output with unique reference');
console.log(output);

let o2 = {
  id: 'p1',
  isOptional: false,
  item: {
    id: 10
  }
};

let obj2 = {
  requests: [o, o2]
}
let output2 = [...new Set(obj2.requests)];
console.log('Output with different references');
console.log(output2);
```