# How to concataecance object array values of duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, filter

I have an object that contains duplicate `id` properties and I want to reduce them to one array for each. I only figured out a way to find unique `id`s, but how can I concat the `name` attribute?

```
const x = [
   {id: 1, name: 'green'},
   {id: 2, name: 'red'},
   {id: 1, name: 'blue'}
]
```

Desired result:

```
[
   {id: 1, name: 'green, blue'},
   {id: 2, name: 'red'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple reduce to combine and using Object.values to get the result you are after.

```js
const x = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'green'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'red'
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'blue'
  }
]

const result = Object.values(x.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (acc[obj.id]) {
    acc[obj.id].name += ", " + obj.name;
  } else {
    acc[obj.id] = { ...obj
    };
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Iterate over `x` using [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) while using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to store `id` as `key` and the array element as the `value`
2. If the `map` already has a record with this `id`, just concatenate the name to it
3. Otherwise, add a new record to it
4. In the end, the `values` of the `map` will contain all the array elements grouped by the `id` and having the `name` to include all of them.

```js
const x = [ { id: 1, name: 'green' }, { id: 2, name: 'red' }, { id: 1, name: 'blue' }
];

const res = [...x.reduce((map, {id, name}) => {
  if(map.has(id)) map.get(id).name += `, ${name}`;
  else map.set(id, { id, name });
  return map;
}, new Map)
.values()
];

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using `Set` to get a list of [unique ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript).

Then, using `filter` and `map` we get all the matching objects, and `join` the names together.

```js
const x = [
   {id: 1, name: 'green'},
   {id: 2, name: 'red'},
   {id: 1, name: 'blue'}
]

const result = [];
const uniqueIds = [...new Set(x.map(item => item.id))];
const merged = uniqueIds.forEach((id) => {
  
  // Matching ids
  const match = x.filter((o) => o.id === id);
  
  // Names of matching ids
  const names =  match.map(x => x.name);
  
  // Add new
  result.push({
    id,
    names: names.join(', ')
  });
});

console.log(result);
```