# How to get disinct values from an array prop inside an array of objects using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

So say i have a dataset like this.

```js
posts = [
{
  title: 'title1',
  category: 'cat1',
  tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4']
},
{
  title: 'title2',
  category: 'cat1',
  tags: ['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag5']
}];
```

I'd like to get a list of the unique tags in all the posts like so:

```js
['tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3', 'tag4', 'tag5']
```

I found [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript) that covers how to this for a single prop:

```js
const categories = [...new Set(posts.map(post => post.category))];
```

But I can't seem to get the syntax for tags. Something like this (predictably), adds the arrays instead of the destructed values:

```js
const tags = [...new Set(posts.map(post => post.tags))];
```

Obviously I can loop through each post and the grab them that way, but I'm sure there's a more elegant way using ES6 that I just haven't figured out yet. Any thoughts here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` to get a flattened array of tags to create the Set:

```js
const posts = [{"title":"title1","category":"cat1","tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"]},{"title":"title2","category":"cat1","tags":["tag1","tag2","tag5"]}];

const result = [...new Set(posts.flatMap(p => p.tags))];

console.log(result);
```

If `Array.flatMap()` is not supported, you can spread the array of arrays created by your `Array.map()` into `Array.concat()` to flatten it:

```js
const posts = [{"title":"title1","category":"cat1","tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4"]},{"title":"title2","category":"cat1","tags":["tag1","tag2","tag5"]}];

const result = [...new Set([].concat(...posts.map(p => p.tags)))];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks, `flatMap` worked. Every time I think I am getting a grasp on all the js and es6 tricks, I come across another one I didn't know about! cheers 

Comment: You're welcome. `Array.flatMap()` is not actually part of ES6, but a later version, and that's why I added a fallback.