# Extract an elelment's property without repetitions from an array of objects, obtained from an API, in Vue 2

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object, vuejs2

I have this array of objects working fine obtained from an API in `mounted` in Vue.

```
0:
author: (...)
genre: ("Rock")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)

1:
author: (...)
genre: ("Pop")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)

2:
author: (...)
genre: ("Jazz")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)


3:
author: (...)
genre: ("Rock")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)

4:
author: (...)
genre: ("Pop")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)

5:
author: (...)
genre: ("Jazz")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)


6:
author: (...)
genre: ("Rock")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)

7:
author: (...)
genre: ("Pop")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)

8:
author: (...)
genre: ("Jazz")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)

9:
author: (...)
genre: ("Jazz")
poster: (...)
title: (...)
year: (...)
```

I have this `<select>` that I want to fill with the `genre` seen in the previous array, but without repetitions.

```
<div class="select-genre">
                <label for="genre">Genre</label>
                <select id="genre" name="genre">
                    <option value="">Seleziona</option>
                    <option v-for="(element, index) in cds" :value="cds.genre">{{ element.genre }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
```

The way I did in HTML prints every genre with repetitions, so my idea was to filter the original array to obtain a new one with only the three genres present once.
The problem is the original array populates itself after the filter, I've seen its `console.log` after the filter one, so I did this way to prevent this thing.

```
if (this.cds.length == 10) {
    const genres = this.cds.filter((element) => {
    return element.genre != element.genre;
}
```

So it starts to filter only when the original array contains 10 elements.
Outside of my `if statement` I've written:

```
this.genreArray = [...genres];
console.log('Genere', this.genreArray);
```

To obtain the genre of the `element` only when it's different and then I would have saved `const genres` inside an empty array in `data`, that is `genreArray`, to obtain the new array with the genres repeated once.
Where have I been wrong?

Comment: See this previous [SO question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your filter function is not correct. the `element.genre != element.genre` condition is always false because it is comparing the same element to itself each time.

you can do something like this:

```js
if (this.cds.length == 10) {
    const genres = {};
    this.cds.forEach((element) => {
       if(!genres[element.genre]) {
          genres[element.genre] = element;
       }
    });
}
this.genreArray = Object.values(genres);
```