# Converting An array of object in to an object with different object and array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting, object

sorry for the title I don't even know how to explain this problem I'm having without showing it. so down below is the data I'm getting from the database

```
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "patientEmail": "pleipnik0@multiply.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Port",
  "patientLastname": "Leipnik",
  "createdAt": "2021-03-13T20:29:24Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "patientEmail": "dwhye1@cdc.gov",
  "patientFirstname": "Dorelia",
  "patientLastname": "Whye",
  "createdAt": "2020-09-04T09:46:42Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "patientEmail": "kmacmichael2@fotki.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Kerwin",
  "patientLastname": "MacMichael",
  "createdAt": "2021-05-29T08:38:39Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "patientEmail": "kgarrand3@live.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Kristien",
  "patientLastname": "Garrand",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-18T22:22:19Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "patientEmail": "ogardiner4@earthlink.net",
  "patientFirstname": "Orel",
  "patientLastname": "Gardiner",
  "createdAt": "2021-01-09T20:12:47Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "patientEmail": "hfarreil5@tripod.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Hortensia",
  "patientLastname": "Farreil",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-17T15:34:48Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "patientEmail": "kkeetley6@gmpg.org",
  "patientFirstname": "Kassandra",
  "patientLastname": "Keetley",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-19T11:44:19Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "patientEmail": "jjanauschek7@arstechnica.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Jorie",
  "patientLastname": "Janauschek",
  "createdAt": "2021-03-22T04:57:21Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "patientEmail": "mdeporte8@ibm.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Mattias",
  "patientLastname": "Deporte",
  "createdAt": "2021-01-26T16:12:06Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "patientEmail": "clerwill9@google.es",
  "patientFirstname": "Cal",
  "patientLastname": "Lerwill",
  "createdAt": "2021-02-04T06:07:47Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 11,
  "patientEmail": "egasparroa@flavors.me",
  "patientFirstname": "Euphemia",
  "patientLastname": "Gasparro",
  "createdAt": "2021-02-14T09:17:12Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "patientEmail": "amellodeyb@ucla.edu",
  "patientFirstname": "Andria",
  "patientLastname": "Mellodey",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-26T04:47:39Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 13,
  "patientEmail": "kridec@example.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Kerwin",
  "patientLastname": "Ride",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-23T13:00:26Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 14,
  "patientEmail": "dshottond@privacy.gov.au",
  "patientFirstname": "Dodie",
  "patientLastname": "Shotton",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-16T20:18:49Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 15,
  "patientEmail": "emytone@aboutads.info",
  "patientFirstname": "Estrella",
  "patientLastname": "Myton",
  "createdAt": "2021-05-19T10:01:56Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 16,
  "patientEmail": "rriditchf@paypal.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Rosabel",
  "patientLastname": "Riditch",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-06T00:04:51Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 17,
  "patientEmail": "hrushfordg@altervista.org",
  "patientFirstname": "Hatti",
  "patientLastname": "Rushford",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-25T11:35:25Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 18,
  "patientEmail": "cgoldhillh@google.com.br",
  "patientFirstname": "Clemmie",
  "patientLastname": "Goldhill",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-07T19:15:11Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 19,
  "patientEmail": "pcochi@alexa.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Pattie",
  "patientLastname": "Coch",
  "createdAt": "2020-08-23T07:53:19Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 20,
  "patientEmail": "abarnbyj@addtoany.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Aline",
  "patientLastname": "Barnby",
  "createdAt": "2020-12-01T09:54:53Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}]
```

I would like to run a function that will convert it to this:

```
const convertedData = {
    // labels are the createdAt months I will momentjs to pull that out
    labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr"],
    datasets: [
      {
        status: "COMPLETED",
        // data is an array of occurrence for each label
        // so this will be Jan -> 3, Feb -> 7 etc
        // for example they were 3 COMPLETED for Jan so the first element of the array will be 3 and
        // 7 for Feb etc...
        // so this goes for the all 3 statuses
        data: [3, 7, 4, 6],
      },
      {
        status: "UNCOMPLETED",
        data: [4, 3, 5, 2],
      },
      {
        status: "PENDING",
        data: [7, 2, 6, 8],
      },
    ],
  }
```

I have tried every possible solution I could think of and I tried some of that kinda work but they were long and I know there must be an easy solution for this. I'm trying to use the converted data on a chart.

Edit: createdAt was not formated the correct way wouldn't work with momentjs

Comment: show your best attempt, what's wrong with it?

Comment: why do you declare it as const? why not a multi-dimensional array? i can help you if 
 you convert it to a multi-dimensional array  for me.

Comment: @Joshua this is just mock data and that's how it coming back from the database

Comment: @Bravo so I will do something like this for each and every month 

`const janCompleted = data.filter(d => d.status === "COMPLETED" && moment(d.createdAt).format("MMM") === "Mar")` as you can see this is not ideal at all as I would have to repeat this for every month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a logic for grouping the same.

Steps followed.

1. Find the unique set of values for `status`.
2. Group the array with month and push the count of induvidual status into the array.

Please find the working sample below.

```js
const data = [{
  "id": 1,
  "patientEmail": "pleipnik0@multiply.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Port",
  "patientLastname": "Leipnik",
  "createdAt": "2021-03-13T20:29:24Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "patientEmail": "dwhye1@cdc.gov",
  "patientFirstname": "Dorelia",
  "patientLastname": "Whye",
  "createdAt": "2020-09-04T09:46:42Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "patientEmail": "kmacmichael2@fotki.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Kerwin",
  "patientLastname": "MacMichael",
  "createdAt": "2021-05-29T08:38:39Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 4,
  "patientEmail": "kgarrand3@live.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Kristien",
  "patientLastname": "Garrand",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-18T22:22:19Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "patientEmail": "ogardiner4@earthlink.net",
  "patientFirstname": "Orel",
  "patientLastname": "Gardiner",
  "createdAt": "2021-01-09T20:12:47Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 6,
  "patientEmail": "hfarreil5@tripod.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Hortensia",
  "patientLastname": "Farreil",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-17T15:34:48Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 7,
  "patientEmail": "kkeetley6@gmpg.org",
  "patientFirstname": "Kassandra",
  "patientLastname": "Keetley",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-19T11:44:19Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 8,
  "patientEmail": "jjanauschek7@arstechnica.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Jorie",
  "patientLastname": "Janauschek",
  "createdAt": "2021-03-22T04:57:21Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 9,
  "patientEmail": "mdeporte8@ibm.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Mattias",
  "patientLastname": "Deporte",
  "createdAt": "2021-01-26T16:12:06Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 10,
  "patientEmail": "clerwill9@google.es",
  "patientFirstname": "Cal",
  "patientLastname": "Lerwill",
  "createdAt": "2021-02-04T06:07:47Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 11,
  "patientEmail": "egasparroa@flavors.me",
  "patientFirstname": "Euphemia",
  "patientLastname": "Gasparro",
  "createdAt": "2021-02-14T09:17:12Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 12,
  "patientEmail": "amellodeyb@ucla.edu",
  "patientFirstname": "Andria",
  "patientLastname": "Mellodey",
  "createdAt": "2020-07-26T04:47:39Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 13,
  "patientEmail": "kridec@example.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Kerwin",
  "patientLastname": "Ride",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-23T13:00:26Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 14,
  "patientEmail": "dshottond@privacy.gov.au",
  "patientFirstname": "Dodie",
  "patientLastname": "Shotton",
  "createdAt": "2021-04-16T20:18:49Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 15,
  "patientEmail": "emytone@aboutads.info",
  "patientFirstname": "Estrella",
  "patientLastname": "Myton",
  "createdAt": "2021-05-19T10:01:56Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 16,
  "patientEmail": "rriditchf@paypal.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Rosabel",
  "patientLastname": "Riditch",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-06T00:04:51Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 17,
  "patientEmail": "hrushfordg@altervista.org",
  "patientFirstname": "Hatti",
  "patientLastname": "Rushford",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-25T11:35:25Z",
  "status": "COMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 18,
  "patientEmail": "cgoldhillh@google.com.br",
  "patientFirstname": "Clemmie",
  "patientLastname": "Goldhill",
  "createdAt": "2020-11-07T19:15:11Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}, {
  "id": 19,
  "patientEmail": "pcochi@alexa.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Pattie",
  "patientLastname": "Coch",
  "createdAt": "2020-08-23T07:53:19Z",
  "status": "UNCOMPLETED"
}, {
  "id": 20,
  "patientEmail": "abarnbyj@addtoany.com",
  "patientFirstname": "Aline",
  "patientLastname": "Barnby",
  "createdAt": "2020-12-01T09:54:53Z",
  "status": "PENDING"
}];
const convertedData = {
  labels: [],
  datasets: [],
}
data.forEach((node) => {
  const month = moment(node.createdAt).format('MMM');
  node.month = month;
});
const uniqueStatus = findUnqueValues(data, 'status');
uniqueStatus.forEach(status => convertedData.datasets.push({
  status,
  data: [],
}))

data.forEach((node) => {
  if (convertedData.labels.indexOf(node.month) === -1) {
    convertedData.labels.push(node.month);
    // Pick up nodes Having same months
    const nodesWithSameMonth = data.filter((item) => item.month === node.month);
    convertedData.datasets.forEach(x => {
        // From the lst of nodes with same month filter out nodes with same status
        const y = nodesWithSameMonth.filter(z => z.status === x.status);
        x.data.push(y.length);
      });
  }
})
console.log(convertedData);

// Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript
function findUnqueValues(array, key) {
  var flags = [], output = [], l = array.length, i;
  for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    if (flags[array[i][key]]) continue;
    flags[array[i][key]] = true;
    output.push(array[i][key]);
  }
  return output;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you so much that solves my problem.