# how to make an array unique using reduce method of javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I have created one example for you to understand the problem.

```js
let arr = [];
arr.push({
  module_id: 41,
  name: 'first'
}, {
  module_id: 41,
  name: 'second',
  important: true,
}, {
  module_id: 43,
  name: 'third'
});

const lookup = arr.reduce((a, e) => {
  a[e.module_id] = ++a[e.module_id] || 0;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log('lookup is', lookup);

let unique = [];
arr.filter((e) => {

  if (lookup[e.module_id] === 0) {
    unique.push(e)
  }
})

console.log('unique', unique)
```

first, I have an empty array `arr` and I am pushing 3 objects in it. 
Notice, the `module_name`. There are two repeatings and I'd like to use the second one with the property name `important`. 
I have used `reduce` here for finding out which one is repeating based on `module_name`. it'll return 1 with the key of 41 and 0 for 43. I want to use both but I don't want to duplicate into my `unique` array. Currently, I'll push only those elements which are unique, in our case `module_id: 43`. 
Now how can I get the duplicate value (with `important` property)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let arr = [];
arr.push(
  {
    module_id: 41,
    name: 'first',
  },
  {
    module_id: 41,
    name: 'second',
    important: true,
  },
  {
    module_id: 43,
    name: 'third',
  }
);


const result = arr.reduce(
  (acc, curr) =>
    acc.find((v) => v.module_id === curr.module_id) ? acc : [...acc, curr],
  []
);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: this does not return the object with important property.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get only distinct first values or the ones with important flag.

```js
const
    array = [{ module_id: 41, name: 'first' }, { module_id: 41, name: 'second', important: true }, { module_id: 43, name: 'third' }],
    result = Array.from(array
        .reduce(
            (m, o) => m.set(o.module_id, !o.important && m.get(o.module_id) || o),
            new Map
        )
        .values()
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
let unique = [];
arr.filter((e) => {

  if (lookup[e.module_id] === 0) {
    unique.push(e)
  }
  else if (e.important) {
    unique.push(e)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5];
const uniqueNums = arr.reduce( (all,item) => {
  if(all.indexOf(item) === -1) {
    all.push(item)
  }
  return all
},[])
```