# how to get unique values from a list of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Data:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Ankh of Anubis",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "ankh-of-anubis"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Bonus Roulette",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "bonus-roulette"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "jetx",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "jetx"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Gates of Olympus",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "trophy",
      "current": "gates-of-olympus"
    }
  },
]
```

How to filter only unique values,

```
uniqueValues = ["medal","trophy"]
```

I tried,

1. `const uniqueTitles = new Set(games.category.title);`
2. `const uniqueTitles = [...new Set(games.category.title)]` //typescript error.
3. 

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const uniqueTitles = games.filter((game:any) => {
      return new Set(game.category.title);
    })
    setTitles(uniqueTitles);
  },[])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Set` as the return value for a filter function. Is it really intended that way?
Given the data:

```
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Ankh of Anubis",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "ankh-of-anubis"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Bonus Roulette",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "bonus-roulette"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "jetx",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "jetx"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Gates of Olympus",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "trophy",
      "current": "gates-of-olympus"
    }
  },
]
```

You can do this:

```
const uniqueValues = new Set();
data.forEach(record => uniqueValues.add(record.rank._type));
console.log(uniqueValues);
```

Here's the [link](http://tpcg.io/_F8ZIJS).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is called `data`:

```
const unique = [...new Set(data.map(item => item.rank._type))];
```

Credits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58429784/6320971

Answer (score 0):

Solution similar to your first try :

```js
const data = [{"name":"Ankh of Anubis","rank":{"_type":"medal","current":"ankh-of-anubis"}},{"name":"Bonus Roulette","rank":{"_type":"medal","current":"bonus-roulette"}},{"name":"jetx","rank":{"_type":"medal","current":"jetx"}},{"name":"Gates of Olympus","rank":{"_type":"trophy","current":"gates-of-olympus"}},];

const uniqueValues = new Set(data.map(elem => elem.rank._type));
uniqueValues.forEach(value => console.log(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "Ankh of Anubis",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "ankh-of-anubis"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Bonus Roulette",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "bonus-roulette"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "jetx",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "medal",
      "current": "jetx"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "Gates of Olympus",
    "rank": {
      "_type": "trophy",
      "current": "gates-of-olympus"
    }
  },
]

const result = data.filter((item, index) => {
  const itemIndex = data.findIndex(i => i.rank._type === item.rank._type)
  return itemIndex === index
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

```
Array.from(new Set(dataList.map(i => i.name)))
```