# How to get unique values from an array of objects in JavaScript, but filtered by certain value

Tags: javascript

I would like to extend the question that has been asked some time ago: [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

my case is very similar:
I have the following:

```
var array = 
    [
        {"name":"Doctor", "age":17}, 
        {"name":"Doctor", "age":17},
        {"name":"Doctor", "age":18},
        {"name":"Nurse", "age":17}, 
        {"name":"Nurse", "age": 35}
        {"name":"Nurse", "age": 35}
    ]
```

What is the best way to be able to get an array of all of the distinct ages, but for chosen speciality such that I get an result array of:

filter by `doctor` parameter:
`[17, 18]`

filter by `nurse` parameter: `[17, 35]`

Comment: Maybe `.filter` then pass that to `new Set`?

Comment: do you mean just filter first and then apply something like: `array.map(item => item.age)
  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)`

Comment: I'd like to know what med-school hands out medical degrees to high-school kids...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array functions

```js
const array = [{
    "name": "Doctor",
    "age": 17
  },
  {
    "name": "Doctor",
    "age": 18
  },
  {
    "name": "Nurse",
    "age": 17
  },
  {
    "name": "Nurse",
    "age": 35
  }
]

console.log(getUniqueAges(array, 'Doctor'))
console.log(getUniqueAges(array, 'Nurse'))

function getUniqueAges(data, name) {
  return [...new Set(data
    .filter(datum => datum.name === name)
    .map(datum => datum.age))]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just like in the answer you linked, but you filter (the example below is filtered by name==="doctor) the array before you pass it to the Set:

```
const data =     [
    {"name":"Doctor", "age":17}, 
    {"name":"Doctor", "age":18},
    {"name":"Nurse", "age":17}, 
    {"name":"Nurse", "age": 35}
];
const unique = [...new Set(data.filter(item => item.name === "doctor").map(item => item.age))]; // [ '17', '18']
```

Comment: your solution works well, but was second, so I can give you only the point up