# How to get a unique array of objects from a given array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, filter

```
let array = [{
    "name": "A",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "A",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "age": 35
  },
{
    "name": "C",
    "age": 32
  }
]
```

How to get a unique array of objects for above array.

output array:

```
 [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "age": 12
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "age": 35
  },
{
    "name": "C",
    "age": 32
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: @mgm793 I think the question I closed with is a better dupe of this

Comment: what if you had `name:"A", age:12` and `name:"A", age:13` are they duplicates?