# How do I filter the unique values of a list using only integers or lists and without using any functions in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, list, filtering, code.org

I need to identify the unique values and put it to another list so that there are no repeated values in the other list. I cannot use functions like .filter() or .includes() or .push() anything like that because I am doing this on Code.org which is what my school uses and they restrict a lot of functions that I normally use.

I've tried:

```
function contains(city) {
  appendItem(filteredLocations, locations[0]);
 for (var i = 0; i <locations.length; i++);
  if (filteredLocations[i] != city){
    appendItem(filteredLocations, locations[i]);
  }
  else {
    i++;
  }
}`
```

and this:

```
function fillDropdowns(){ 
 //filter the cities
 for (var i = 0; i < locations.length;i++){
   if (contains(locations[i]) == true) {
     appendItem(filteredLocations, locations[i]);
   }
   else {
     i++;
   }
 }
 //locations list
 
}
function contains(city) {
 for (var i = 0; i < filteredLocations.length; i++);
  if (filteredLocations[i] == city){
    return true;
  }
}
```

And some others that I have deleted.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15125953/13762301

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

Comment: The above *is* a duplicate and offers answers that don't use more recent array methods as linked in my first comment. Take the time to read more than the top answer when looking for help, especially on older well trafficked topics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to implement a js lookup object to check whether a key is unique or not.

```js
const locations = ["Munich", "Frankfurt", "Nuremberg", "Munich", "Frankfurt"];

const dict = {}; //Look up object 
const uniqueCities = [];

for (let i = 0, j = 0; i < locations.length; ++i) {
  const city = locations[i];
  if (!dict[city]) { //if city is not in "dict" that means it's an unque city
    dict[city] = true; //pushing the unique city to "dict" because it's not unique anymore
    uniqueCities[j++] = city;
  }
}

console.log(uniqueCities);
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked!!! Although I have a question. The first time the for loop runs, there is nothing in the dictionary, so how can it check for the key of the constant city is in the dictionary if the dictionary is empty. Shouldn't there be an error?

Comment: When a key is not present in the object, you'll get `undefined` so I'm just checking it. There are other ways to accomplish this task for example by using `in` keyword like `key in obj` or using `hasOwnProperty()`.