# Typescript - How to merge the objects that have the name and car in common and do the sum of the values ​of the key value1 and value2

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have an array with the following objects:

```
public names: Array<any> = [
 {name: 'John', car:'BMW',  value1: 500, value2: 350},
 {name: 'John', car:'AUDI',  value1: 500, value2: 350},
 {name: 'John', car:'AUDI',  value1: 250, value2: 200},
 {name: 'Paul', car: 'AUDI',  value1: 290, value2: 200},
 {name: 'John', car:'BMW',  value1: 600, value2: 360},
 {name: 'John', car:'BMW',  value1: 500, value2: 350},
 {name: 'Paul', car: 'AUDI',  value1: 120, value2: 50},
 {name: 'John', car:'BMW',  value1: 100, value2: 100},
];
```

I would like to merge them passing the common `name` and `car` as a reference and do the sum of `value1` and `value2` according to the result below. I tried to use `reduce` but I think I'm wrong in the type.

Expected result:

```
[
 {name: 'John', car:'BMW', value1: 1700, value2: 1160},
 {name: 'John', car:'AUDI', value1: 750, value2: 550},
 {name: 'Paul', car: 'AUDI', value1: 410, value2: 250}
]
```

I tried to do by reduce but I think I got the type wrong.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far

Comment: ... and the error message you got.

Answer (score 0):

look at the answer in this question
[How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)

with this you can get the distinct list of objects. After that iterate over all your objects and increment the value props on the elements where your two key properties fit

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).