# Word Frequency Count, fix a bug with standard property

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to build a javascript function which would count the number of occurrences of each word in an input array.

Example :

Input

```
a=["a","booster","booster","constructor","adam","adam","adam","adam"]
```

Output:

```
"a":1
"booster":2
"constructor":1
"adam":4
```

Output should be dict-alike.

I'm new to javascript and I tried to use a dict. But objects have a property called "constructor", so **cnt["constructor"]** seems not to work.

Here is my code and the result:

```
var cnt={};
console.log("constructor");

for(var i=0;i<a.length;++i)
{
    if(! (a[i] in cnt))
        cnt[a[i]]=0;
    else
        cnt[a[i]]+=1;
}

for(var item in cnt)
    console.log(item+":"+cnt[item]);
```

Result:

[image]

You can see that 1 is added to constructor of cnt as a string.

Comment: Interesting question actually. Instead of blindly downvoting, try to solve the OP problem. Is it important if he tried anything or not?

Comment: I just don't know why this question is downvoted. It seems that array can't support the same usage as map in C++ STL because the properties.

Comment: @dfsq I agree with you, however, it's easier to understand the actual problem with some code provided.

Comment: @Pinal, I've edited my question and added my code.

Comment: @Andy, Question has been edited.

Comment: Ok, +1 for prevent removing this question :)

Comment: @Pinal. This question is already answered. Hope to see your answer if you have a better one.

Comment: WOW!  Very odd.  I'm seeing it add a constructor function too?!!?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
function count(arr){
  return arr.reduce(function(m,e){
    m[e] = (+m[e]||0)+1; return m
  },{});
}
```

The idea behind are

- the use of `reduce` for elegance
- the conversion of `m[e]` to a number using `+m[e]` to avoid the `constructor` (or `toString`) problem

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/fiba/1/)

Comment: If you log the constructor property of your result, you can find that an odd "1" is added to the constructor of the array. That's exactly where the key point is.

Comment: I've tried using array. Do you know whether javascript has map?

Comment: This code uses a map. In JavaScript we usually call map an object that is used to map properties to values.

Comment: I'd like to know why there's a downvote here. Did somebody find a bug ?

Comment: It is my downvote just now. You can see my edited question now and will find why this code is not correct.

Comment: Oh, sorry, didn't see your change maybe because of the network. This works exactly! Thank you so much!

Comment: I just edited. This makes the code much longer (1 char) and more boring but also probably much more readable.

Comment: Thank you again! By the way, you added a "+" comparing to your answer at the first time. But why does your first answer fail but this works?

Comment: @Booster because `+"constructor"` is NaN, so `(+"constructor"||0)` is `0`

Comment: Really good answer. Is this question boring or something else? Why are  there some people downvoting?

Comment: @Booster Because there was no code initially and because you weren't clear at all with the problem you had encountered with "constructor". It's a good question but the way it was initially asked made it appear bad (even to me).

Comment: Oh...Really sorry for my bad description and ugly english.

Comment: @Booster Don't worry, you have 3 supporters : `+3/-8` :D

Comment: @wared, I don't care about reputations. However, I think this question should help a lot of beginners like me. If this question is not noticed just because of my bad description, it's a great loss.

Comment: @Booster I agree with you (the answer is pretty interesting by the way), that why I voted up. Take care to post well prepared and detailed question next time :)

Comment: Whether this works or not, no one understands your code.

Comment: @EliseChant Obviously most coders and voters understand it. What's unclear for you ?

Comment: @dystroy with all due respect line 3

Comment: `+m[e]` is the conversion of `m[e]` to a number. If `m[e]` isn't yet defined then `+m[e]` is `NaN` and thus `+m[e]||0` is `0` (initial case) .

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'apple'];
var initialValue = {};

var result = arr.reduce(function(accumulator, curr, idx, arr) {
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.call(accumulator, curr)) {   // does current exist as key on initialValue object?
        accumulator[curr]++;
    } else {    // no key for current on initialValue object
        accumulator[curr] = 1;
    }
    return accumulator;
}, initialValue);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an array just by initializing [] as the initial accumulator.

```
var fruits = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'apple'].reduce((countFruits,currentFruit)=>{
  if(typeof countFruits[currentFruit]!=="undefined"){
    countFruits[currentFruit] = countFruits[currentFruit]+1
    return countFruits
  }
  countFruits[currentFruit] = 1
  return countFruits
},[])
console.log(fruits)
```