# Find maximum occurance of string element in an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, count

I have an Array of string elements and I need to find how many times a elements occured in a Array.
my Array is following:
**var x=["water","water","water","land", "land","land","land","forest"];**

I need to know which element is prominent in Array. I have tried to use example from this discussion "[Counting the occurrences of JavaScript array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-occurences-of-javascript-array-elements)".
But I did not get any expected result.
Please help me to find a possible solution. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be an unambiguous answer to which item occurs the most times. Here is how you can get the item counts in a functional style:

```
x.reduce(function(counts, key) { 
  if(!counts.hasOwnProperty(key))
    counts[key] = 0
  counts[key] = counts[key] + 1
  return counts }, {})
```

Returns {"water": 3, "land": 4, "forest": 1}

Comment: May be I am doing some mistake in my steps. Could you please take a look of my codes:'var x=["water","water","water","land", "land","land","land","forest"];
var counts = {};
x.reduce(function(counts, key) { 
  if(!counts.hasOwnProperty(key))
    counts[key] = 0;
  counts[key] = counts[key] + 1;
    return counts; },{});
 
alert(counts);' It Shows code is valid but Returns like this:[objectobject]  --Thanks a lot:-)

Comment: It returns a javascript object with the items as keys. You can get a readable string representation with JSON.stringify(x)