# Regroup array to match arrangement of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to regroup these two arrays:

```
arrayOne = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'C'];
arrayTwo = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'];
```

Here's the output I'm looking for:

```
groupedOutput = {
  'A': ['1', '5'],
  'B': ['2'],
  'C': ['3', '6'],
  'D': ['4']
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: something like this maybe:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-occurences-of-javascript-array-elements

Comment: Andy, I need to match the indexes of both arrays. As a result, I want to have two-dimensional array, where:

`element[0][0]='A';
element[0][1]=['1','5'];

element[1][0]='B';
element[1][1]=['2'];

element[2][0]='C';
element[2][1]=['3','6'];

element[3][0]='D';
element[3][1]=['4'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code(but I left somethings for you to do):

```
var aar = [][]
for(var i = 0 ; i<arrayone.length ; i++)
{
    arr[i][0] = arrayone[i];
    arr[i][1] = arraytwo[i];
}
for(var i = 0 ; i<arrayone.length ; i++)
{
    for(var j = i ; j<arrayone.length ; j++)
    {
        if(arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
           arr[i][1] = arr[i][1] + " , " + arr[j][1];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var groupedObj = {};
for(var i = 0; i< arrayOne.length; i ++) {
    if (typeof groupedObj[arrayOne[i]] === "undefined") groupedObj[arrayOne[i]] = [];
    groupedObj[arrayOne[i]].push(arrayTwo[i]);
}
```

groupedObj will contain your desired result

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be an array.