# Counting the number of times each value in the array appears in that array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got a question as to how I should go about performing some math over an array.  My apologies if this is a basic question, javascript is not my strongest language and I'm a mediocre programmer on my best days.

I have an array of values and as part of an analysis, I'm performing a mann-kendall test, but I've hit a wall where I'm calculating the variance.
(http://vsp.pnnl.gov/help/Vsample/Design_Trend_Mann_Kendall.htm   Step #6)

Essentially, I'd like to count the number of times each value in the array appears in that array.
So for instance at a particular pixel of the world, the array might look like:

```
[1, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.7, 1]
```

I need to count the number of times a particular value appears, then run the expression
    Expression(value*(value-1)*(value*2+5));

So for that array, I want the distinct value counts...

```
1: 5  
0.7: 2  
0.8: 2  
0.3: 1
```

And then compute the value of those "ties" as a part of the expression...

```
5 * (5-1) * (5*2 -5) +   
2 * (2-1) * (2*2 -5) +   
2 * (2-1) * (2*2 -5) +   
1 * (1-1) * (1*2 -5)
```

A few notes:

- This is Javascript for maps (think google map engine), so some of the more standard Javascript answers might not work (I have already tried a few variations of the scripts from the other SO threads ([Counting occurences of Javascript array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-occurences-of-javascript-array-elements).)
- These arrays are unique to each pixel across the planet, so I think
  the best way to do this would be as a function.
- As seen above, values with a count of 1 fall out, which is fine, however, I need to avoid double counting items so simply transforming
  the array into counts (`[5, 5, 2, 1, 5, 2, 5, 2, 2, 5]`) is
  incorrect.
- I am limited to the standard Javascript library.

Comment: So to put it in a nutshell, you want to create a dict (map) where key value is the array val, and the map vlaue is their occurence count, yes?

Comment: That sounds right, however, accessing them seems to be the hardest part.  
As an update: I have tried a few of the answers below and .forEach doesn't seem to work, the system throws a "not a function" error.  Much of the issue here is that I'm using a beta platform and the array features don't jive with my previous experiences using arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var arr = [1, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.7, 1];
document.write(compute(arr));
 
function compute(arr){
    freq = {};
    for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        freq[arr[i]] = (freq[arr[i]] || 0) + 1;
    }
    
    var sum = 0;
    for(var i in freq){
        sum += freq[i]*(freq[i]-1)*(freq[i]*2-5);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: This can be written more idiomatically as `freq[v] = (freq[v] || 0) + 1`

Comment: A very readable code, but the .forEach doesn't seem to work, the system throws a "not a function" error.  Is there an elegant way around using it?

Comment: @JamesColl , I replaced it with the for loop.

Comment: Fantastic!  However, I now get an image that has the constant '0' mapped across it.  It seems to not loop through the last for loop and change the value of sum; do you have any idea why?

Comment: You mean the input array is [0]?

Comment: No, the output seems to take on the value of whatever I place in the sum field (i.e. a sum = 1 returns a constant image of "1")

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo(arr) {
    var a = [], b = [], prev;
    arr.sort();
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(arr[i]);
            b.push(1);
        } else {
            b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }
    return [a, b];
}

var arr = [1, 1, 0.7, 0.3, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 0.7, 1];
var result = foo(arr);
// result[0] contain unique array elements and result[1] contain number of occurrences of those elements
for(var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++){
    document.write(result[0][i] + " : " + result[1][i] + "<br>");
}
```