# Count appearance of each character

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently working on a password strength calculator and then I need to know if a character appears more than once.
I know I must use `regex` like this `occurance = password.match(/a/g).length` to get ho many times `a` occurs, but I want to do that with each character (letter, number, symbol).

Is there a way to do that using JS / JQuery, maybe regex, other than working with an array which contains all characters I want to test ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27224509/counting-the-number-of-times-each-value-in-the-array-appears-in-that-array-java?rq=1

Does that help? You can convert the string to an array of characters and use that method

Comment: `password.length`? Not sure if I understand. Please clarify the desired output.

Comment: @SlashmanX Seems to be good. I try it and tell you how it goes

Comment: Did you tried something...can you show some code

Comment: @Oriol I need the occurance of each character in the password, not the length of password :)

Comment: @SlashmanX Exactly what I need it, thank you ! Feel free to post it on an answer !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var hello = "Hello world";
var histogram = {};

for (var i = 0, len = hello.length; i < len; i++) {
    var letter = hello[i];
    histogram[letter] = (histogram[letter] || 0) + 1;
}

console.log(histogram);
```

Result:

```
{ H: 1, e: 1, l: 3, o: 2, ' ': 1, w: 1, r: 1, d: 1 }
```

Or you may use array. Just change `{}` to `[]`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked as I wanted !! Btw, I'm using a string, so the `{}` was good. Also, you can use `histogram[letter] = (histogram[letter] || 0)+1` instead of your `if / else` condition. As you prefer

Answer (score 5):

From @Noel Jose 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27224859/1063819), you can simply run this function after converting the string to an array `string.split('')`.

```
function foo(arr) {
    var a = [], b = [], prev;
    arr.sort();
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ){
        if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
            a.push(arr[i]);
            b.push(1);
        } else {
            b[b.length-1]++;
        }
        prev = arr[i];
    }
    return [a, b];
}

var stringToCheck = 'password';
var result = foo(stringToCheck.split(''));
// result[0] contain unique array elements and result[1] contain number of occurrences of those elements
for(var i = 0; i < result[0].length; i++){
    console.log(result[0][i] + " : " + result[1][i]);
}
```

Passing in 'testing' will result in the following output:

```
e : 1
g : 1
i : 1
n : 1
s : 1
t : 2
```

Comment: Haha. I was thinking of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27224747/4864023) while talking about this post ^^ But you brought me there so you deserve this answer !! Thanks again !

Comment: @tektiv that answer had some extra calculations in it, so I decided to post the simpler one. At least you got what you were looking for

Answer (score 3):

```
function rall(r, s) {
 var a=[],t,g=r.global;
 do {t=r.exec(s);if (!t) break;
     a.push(t);} while (g);
 return a;
}

var r=/.*?(.)(?=(.*?\1.*))/g;
var res=rall(r,password);
```

`res` will be an array of arrays containing all matches of repeating characters.

The RegExp uses a look ahead to find out whether a found character (captured in the first group) will re-appear later in the string.

A password like `secret elements` would come up as:

```
"[["s","s","ecret elements"],
 ["e","e","cret elements"],
 ["cre","e","t elements"],
 ["t","t"," elements"],
 [" e","e","lements"],
 ["le","e","ments"]]"
```

The second element in each sub-array is the multiply matched character.

If there are no repetitions the array will have length=0 which is easy to test like:

```
if (rall(r,password).length==0)
  console.log('password is OK!');
```

Comment: Worked well thanks, but hard to undestand at first sight. I prefer `SlashManX`'s solution which is more comprehensible

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use an "array-based" solution, you can try something like this:

```
var password= "abcdsa";
var freq = [];
for(var i = 0 ; i < password.length ; i++){
  freq[password[i]] = (freq[password[i]] || 0)+1;
}
```

You iterate through the password once, and keep track of the ocurrances of each character that you find. 
In this case the array "freq" would have something like this:

```
freq["a"] = 2;
freq["b"] = 1;
freq["c"] = 1;
freq["d"] = 1:
freq["s"] = 1;
```

Comment: That works well, thank you for this. However, instead of using `if / else` condition, you can also use `freq[password[i]] == (freq[password[i]] || 0)+1`

Comment: Yeah sure, that would be a "cleaner" approach!

Answer (score 0):

Simply reduce your string into a count object. Seed the reduction with an empty object, each time a letter is encountered then that letter receives a +1 in the object where the index is the letter.

Made into a reusable function

```
function charCount(str){
 return [].reduce.call(str,function(p,c){
  p[c] = p[c] ? p[c]+1 : 1; 
  return p;
 },{});
}

charCount("hello");//Object {h: 1, e: 1, l: 2, o: 1}
```