# Set values to dinamically created object using a loop

Tags: javascript

I created an array from letters of a large string. Now I want to create an object which says how many times that letter is repeated in the array, but I can`t find a solution, please help me out a little.

This is what I done so far:

```
var str = "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo commodi sint fuga autem nobis atque possimus";
var arr = str.split("");

arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  if (e === " ") {
    //var index = arr.indexOf(e);
    arr.splice(i, 1);
  }
});

var obj = {};
var counter = 0;

arr.forEach(function(e, i) {
  obj[e] = 1;
});

arr2 = Object.keys(obj);
var counter = 0;

for (let c = 0; c < arr.length; c++) {
  for (let b = 0; b < arr2.length; b++) {
    if (arr2[b] == arr[c]) { // to find coincidences
      count++;
      // I'm lost here ..
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first `forEach` loop won't work correctly. Use `arr.filter` instead.

Comment: Or just ignore spaces in the second `forEach` loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count appearance of each character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611680/count-appearance-of-each-character)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment the counter for each letter, not just set it to `1`.

There's no need for the `for` loop at the end, or the `counter` variable. `obj` contains the counts that you want.

```js
var str =
  "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo commodi sint fuga autem nobis atque possimus";

var arr = str.split("");

arr = arr.filter(e => e != " ");

var obj = {};

arr.forEach(function(e) {
  if (e in obj) {
    obj[e]++;
  } else {
    obj[e] = 1;
  }
  // Could also be obj[e] = (obj[e] || 0) + 1
});

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: instead of looping twice (`filter` and than `forEach`) just to remove whitespaces, a simple `delete obj[' ']` would do the job

Comment: Yeah, or just `if (e != " ")` in the second loop. Lots of ways to skin the cat.

Comment: Also, I know `e` represents a single character - not present in an Object prototype, but it's too easy for a beginner to remember this tricky [`in` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) and get used to it, and one day stumble upon `"valueOf" in {} === true`. It's longer but definitely good to know `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "prop")`

Answer (score 0):

As a fan of regex I'd propose a more short solution:

```js
const str = 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo commodi sint fuga autem nobis atque possimus';

const result = {};

Array.prototype.forEach.call(str.replace(/[^\w]/g, ''), letter => {
    if (letter in result) return;
    result[letter] = str.match(new RegExp(letter, 'g')).length;
});

console.log(result);
```

You can change regex `i` flag in order to turn on/off case sensitivity.

Comment: You can use `\W` instead of `[^\w]`... but why use `W` at all, it's the same as `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` which in this multilingual UTF-8 world is something you should avoid even suggesting, unless you're not regexing phrases but some strict properties or data names.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.from() <sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and  [Array.prototype.reduce <sup><sub>*MDN*</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) :

```js
const str = "Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo commodi sint fuga autem nobis atque possimus";

const obj = Array.from(str).reduce((ob, c) => {
  ob[c] = ++ob[c] || 1;
  return ob;
}, {});

delete obj[' ']; // If needed remove data for whitespaces
console.log( obj )
```

---

- *Array.from(String)* will convert a String to Array.
- No need to remove whitespaces, you can do that later using Object `delete`
- `reduce` will iterate over the array "reducing" it to an Object `{}`
- The inner logic `ob[c] = ++ob[c] || 1;` just instantiates the property with the value `1`, otherwise it increments it.