# Count number of ocurrences in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I'm interested in finding out how many times every object in an array occurs.

Here's what I want to do mixed with some pseudo-code of what I think is the way to do it.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,1,1,3,4];

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray[i].AlreadyExistsInAVariable) {
        var[i]+ = 1;
    }
    else {
        CreateAnewVar();
    }
}

var one = 3;
var two = 1;
var three = 2;
var four = 1;
```

Comment: Also to bear in mind, the amount of objects in the array will vary constantly, as well as the amount of types of them.

Comment: almost a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5667888/588079. Solving the problem Fyxerz pointed out would however make it a duplicate.

Comment: Why don't you implement it and test it and improve it until you made it on your own?

Comment: I think you need instead something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/fh0pzxeu/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't actually just create new variable bindings like that. You can, however, dynamically add new properties to an object, which is probably a better match for this problem.  Here's an example that counts up the occurrences of numbers in that array:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,1,1,3,4];

var counts = myArray.reduce(function(result, item) {
    result[item] || (result[item] = 0);
    result[item]++;
    return result;
}, {});

console.log(counts);
```

See it in action here: http://jsbin.com/huduroyite/edit?js,console

Comment: Would appreciate an explanation for the downvote...

Comment: This answer works and seems like a great way of solving my problem, better than working with arrays. However, I don't really understand how you do it... Is there any link I can infor myself a bit more about the function within the reduce?

Comment: @Fyxerz The MDN docs are pretty good: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Answer (score 0):

You should use object to count the occurence of numbers in the array rather than using variables.

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,1,1,3,4];
var counter = {};
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    if (myArray.indexOf(myArray[i])>=0) {
        if(!counter[myArray[i]]){
           counter[myArray[i]]=1;
        }
        else{
           counter[myArray[i]]++;  
        }    
    }
}
console.log(counter);
```

Comment: why this answer is down voted. Providing reason before downvoting is appreciated

Comment: this is pretty much exactly how I would do it. But I don't think you need the line `if (myArray.indexOf(myArray[i])>=0)` it's just redundant.

Comment: SO is already overflown by these type of questions! Also it seems OP did not put any efforts to atleast search before posting it on SO.

Comment: @Vicky: so is that the valid reason for down voting?

Comment: I personally did not downvote. But I think it would be fair enough for who did this..

Comment: I do believe the people would downvote the answer only when it is wrong or irrevelant. Downvoting without reason like this would discourage the people to answer or help the questionaire, which I dont feel correct.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,1,1,3,4];

var count = myArray.reduce(function(n, val) {
    return n + (val === 1);
}, 0);

console.log(count);
```

Edit:

For counting occurrences of every element in an array i would do something like this:

```
var result = {};

[1,2,3,1,1,3,4].forEach(function(e, i) {
     result[e] = result[e] + 1 || 1;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(result, null, "\t"));
```

Comment: I can't even begin to fathom what this is trying to do...

Comment: Well, technically it counts the number of occurrences of the number 1, but even then only due to the bizarre type-coercion behavior in JavaScript that causes `<number> + true` to equal `<number> + 1`.

Comment: I didn't read the question correctly. Thought the OP wanted to count the occurrence of a single element.  Care to explain exactly what you mean @jmar777? Doesn't `===` compare without coercing?

Comment: Yes, `===` performs strict equality comparisons, but the result of that comparison is a boolean. Therefore, the `n + (val === 1)` expression results in a `<number> + <boolean>` expression.  I don't know whether it was by design or not, as your solution *technically works* (!!), but that's only due to the fact that, in JavaScript `<number> + true` results in `<number> + 1` as a result.