# Finding the mode's of an array? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Okay, I've only figured out how to get one mode out of the array..
But I want to get 2, 3 or more if they occur the same amount of times.
This is the code:

```
var frequency = {};  // array of frequency.
var maxFreq = 0;  // holds the max frequency.

for (var i in array) {
    frequency[array[i]] = (frequency[array[i]] || 0) + 1; // increment frequency.

    if (frequency[array[i]] > maxFreq) { // is this frequency > max so far ?
        maxFreq = frequency[array[i]];  // update max.
        mode = array[i];          // update result.
    }
}
```

So right now, if I've got a `array = [3, 8, 3, 6, 1, 2, 9];`
I get `mode = 3;`

But what I'm looking for is if `array = [3, 6, 1, 9, 2, 3, 6, 6, 3, 1, -8, 7];`
I want to get the `mode = 3, 6;`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Counting the occurrences of JavaScript array elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-of-javascript-array-elements)

Comment: can you explain these sentences?
"get one mode out of the array"
"get the mode = 3, 6"
thanks,

Comment: Oh, sorry! I want to get the "mode" into a object. This is my object:


    return {
        max: max,
        mean: mean,
        median: median,
        min: min,
        mode: mode,
        range:range

    };

Comment: so I want the mode value to get into the object key (mode)

Comment: @Nit, not a duplicate. Link provided asks for the number of occurrences for **each** number instead of getting number that has maximum number of occurrences

Comment: @Ramen_Lover912 The question and the solution are the same once you consider what you actually need to do.

Comment: after running the code just use a `for in` loop to check for equal occurrences

Answer (score 4):

The question doesn't state how to *get* the modes, but if we want them in an array, we could change the code like this:

```js
function getModes(array) {
  var frequency = []; // array of frequency.
  var maxFreq = 0; // holds the max frequency.
  var modes = [];

  for (var i in array) {
    frequency[array[i]] = (frequency[array[i]] || 0) + 1; // increment frequency.

    if (frequency[array[i]] > maxFreq) { // is this frequency > max so far ?
      maxFreq = frequency[array[i]]; // update max.
    }
  }

  for (var k in frequency) {
    if (frequency[k] == maxFreq) {
      modes.push(k);
    }
  }

  return modes;
}

alert(getModes([3, 6, 1, 9, 2, 3, 6, 6, 3, 1, -8, 7]));
```

Comment: the things is that I want to get the modes into an object, like this:

    return {
        max: max,
        mean: mean,
        median: median,
        min: min,
        mode: [mode],
        range:range

    };

Comment: so how do I pick out modes from the function, best way? 
Cheers!

Comment: The function returns an array of modes. that's what you're asking for.

Comment: yea, I know. But how to get the array into my object so it looks like this instead     return {
        max: max,
        mean: mean,
        median: median,
        min: min,
        mode: [3, 6],
        range:range

    };

Comment: Okay, I get it! :) 
But, the problem is now that I get it as a string,,,I want the [3, 6] as number, How can I fix that problem? Cheers!

Comment: The function doesn't return a string, it returns an array. I think it would be wise of you to take a little time and learn JS from the ground up as you seem to be confusing a lot of things here.

Answer (score 0):

```
function modeCount(data) {
  let modecount = [];
  let valueArr = [];
  let dataSet = new Set(data);
  for (const iterator of dataSet) {
    const filteredNum = data.filter((num) => iterator === num);
    modecount.push({
      mode: iterator,
      count: filteredNum.length
    });
  }

  modecount.sort((a, b) => {
    return b.count - a.count;
  });

  modecount.forEach(value => {
    if (value.count === modecount[0].count) {
      valueArr.push(value.mode);
    }
  });

  return valueArr;
}
let ages = [3, 6, 1, 9, 2, 3, 6, 6, 3, 1, -8, 7]
console.log(modeCount(ages));
```