# Getting Unique value from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have 2 arrays like these ...

```
var browser_names = ["Firefox", "Maxthon", "Opera", "Opera", "Chrome", "Chrome", "Edge", "Firefox"]

var user_count = [3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 20, 94, 142]
```

I want results like these

```
var result_browser_names = ["Firefox", "Maxthon", "Opera", "Chrome", "Edge"]

var result_user_count = [145, 3, 6, 27, 94]
```

As you can see '*result_browser_names*' contains unique browser name values & 
'*result_user_count*' contains 'sum of users' for each type of browser.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-of-javascript-array-elements) solution, which works great for a single array. In my case I have 2 arrays ....

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: by seeing your example, I assume the 2 arrays should be consistent and align with each other all the time? If that's the case, why isn't the solution you link to not working, by doing them separately on both arrays?

Comment: Do you have any specific problem with adapting the one-array solution to two arrays?

Comment: Hi shole & sth. If I run the single array solution to my 'user_count' array. I will get incorrect results.

Comment: Please post the code of what you tried. What happened? What did you expect to happen? What in particular is unclear?

Comment: Hi Robert, Seems like you haven't seen the answer below by Philip. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using an object. Assuming your 2 arrays will always match in length:

```
var browser_names = ["Firefox", "Maxthon", "Opera", "Opera", "Chrome", "Chrome", "Edge", "Firefox"]
var user_count = [3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 20, 94, 142]
var lib = {}

for (var i=0; i < browser_names.length; i++) {
  if (lib[browser_names[i]] != undefined) {
    lib[browser_names[i]] += user_count[i];
  } else {
    lib[browser_names[i]] = user_count[i];
  }
}
```

This should give you the browser names and the cumulative user counts for each browser saved within object `lib`

Also, for the `if` conditional in the loop, you could also do:

```
for (var i=0; i < browser_names.length; i++) {
  if (lib.hasOwnProperty(browser_names[i])) {
    lib[browser_names[i]] += user_count[i];
  } else {
    lib[browser_names[i]] = user_count[i];
  }
}
```

Also, I know your original question was an output to an array. You can easily loop through the keys of the object to get each of their respective browser names and user counts as well:

```
for (var k in lib) {
  console.log(k);         // Browser Names
  console.log(lib[k]);    // Their respective user counts
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single loop and the help from an object as reference to the result arrays.

```js
var browser_names = ["Firefox", "Maxthon", "Opera", "Opera", "Chrome", "Chrome", "Edge", "Firefox"],
    user_count = [3, 3, 3, 3, 7, 20, 94, 142],
    result_browser_names = [],
    result_user_count = [];

browser_names.forEach(function (b, i) {
    if (!(b in this)) {
        this[b] = result_browser_names.push(b) - 1;
        result_user_count.push(0);
    }
    result_user_count[this[b]] += user_count[i];
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(result_browser_names);
console.log(result_user_count);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```