# Using Reduce for unique numbers

Tags: javascript

I am doing some online coding challenges and i was wondering if anyone had a better way of writing a solution for this.

Write a function called 'unique' that will remove all duplicates values from an array.

```
var numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3,9,0,9]; 

 return array.reduce(function(previous, num){

    var checkForRepeat = previous.find(function(x){
      return x === num;
    });

    if(checkForRepeat) {
      return previous;
    } else {
      previous.push(num);
      return previous;
    }
  }, []);
}
unique(numbers);
```

Comment: It's maybe not the direct answer for you question, but there are plenty of examples in there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39599036/javascript-remove-unique-elements-from-array. While waiting for extremely fast solution, try to check the examples in thread I mentioned. Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just do this
`[...new Set(numbers)]`

Answer (score 3):

It can be further optimized by using a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) as lookup of a set is a constant time operation i.e O(1), where as lookup in a array is operation with O(n).

```js
let numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3,9,0,9]; 
function unique(array){
 let set = new Set();
 return array.reduce(function(previous, num){
    if(!set.has(num)){
      previous.push(num);
      set.add(num);
    }
    return previous;
  }, []);
}
numbers = unique(numbers);
console.log(numbers);
```