# GroupBy and count objects in an array in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

This is how my array looks like: and my array is not type of string, it's type of it own object called MyObject (just like setter and getter objects in java)

```
["Car","model","year","color","price"]
["Table","model","year","color","price"]
["Car","model","year","color","price"]
["Car","model","year","color","price"]
["Laptop","model","year","color","price"]
["Laptop","model","year","color","price"]
```

now I want to group by this in typescript and count how many of that item exist in array (also like in sql)

```
name  |count
 Car  | 3
Laptop| 2
Table | 1
```

and in my typescript file I have this

```
private groupByObjects() {
  //this read all data in array allData[] from service
  this.dataService.retrieveData().subscribe(allData => {

});
```

}

Could anyone please help me to write this in **typescript**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a lot and can write the answer which is works for me perfectly. So I post it now and hope it helps anyone who has the same problem as mine.

```
private groupByElement(receivedData: ReceivedData, elements: Array<GroupByElement>) {
    let groupElement: GroupByElement = new GroupByElement;

    if (!elements.find(x => x.element== receivedData.element)) {
      groupElement.element= receivedData.element;
      groupElement.count = 1;
      elements.push(groupElement);
    } else {
      this.updateElementCounter = elements.find(x => x.element== receivedData.element)?.count;
      this.updateElementCounter! += 1;
      this.indexElementCount = elements.findIndex(x => x.element== receivedData.element);

      elements[this.indexElementCount].count = this.updateElementCounter!;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `O(n)` through a simple `reduction`

In your case,

```js
type ApplyFunction<X, T, R> = (all: X, current: T) => R
type GetFunction<T,R> = (t: T) => R

const groupAndApplyByIndex = <T, V extends string | number, R>(data: Array<T>, get: GetFunction<T,V>, apply: ApplyFunction<Record<V, R>, V, R>) => {
  return data.reduce((all, element) => {
    return {
      ...all,
      [get(element)]: apply(all, get(element))
    }
  }, {} as Record<V, R>)
}
```

And just use the above function in your code by

```js
private groupByObjects() {
  //this read all data in array allData[] from service
  this.dataService.retrieveData().subscribe(allData => {

    const getX: GetFunction<string[], string> = (t) => t[0]
    const counts = groupAndApplyByIndex(allData, getX, (all, element) => ((all[element] as number || 0) + 1))

    // Rest of your logic...
  });
```

By using the above method, you have a function which can `count` or do other transformations that you define through `apply`

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.2&ssl=23&ssc=113&pln=10&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQETlOMC8MDaBYAKBlwCIBhOAJxIBoYSBbEAEwFMFb6BPVqzk0AhDU6JAA6UAlsFYkAujULEcJACpwARglmimbDqJ59Rg4fwnTZCpaQoj6e9vyP2BIIa4sz5ioreMOLE6GvK6mnlLe1n4qADJwYlAgYvyOBtyh-OHmkVa+yiTxicmpQekkLlnuZqJeVoRyANyEhFBcYqwwAIJiYghcAGIArmDAUJLgADwAGnSqdABKAHxYMAAUiAgAXDCzMMBDlJSsYFA7qgCUWCsLre2dAOKsUMOj41Pzy6trZzCX1zBbgRCKBILAAOaUEBDMRdMDMHp9LgAIS4AEl4awAB6rSbzGAANRg2KgJ2YEBg0CkYHBMAAPjAwEMGBpWJRFks1sw0HAdl0jnAuHilnRwc8dk8XiMxhMwHiaASRfBev0+SrBtL3nKFqxQJRmJMCRy6EbAUsrpgVgBvGzHKCHMAwbnoAB0x2YQxkaw2SDo7FYDBOUAt1psxDtDpgNr8xGILvjm3yseUYqga39gdOFzkOwSSJ9CFFz3T2kzwYuYZgAF8bFW6Faq-AKTq9QbTcsKwQa8CCKDoDBU9MJc9XjKplTJDScApKVBqeCVtgfiGYFAcAAGOQg8D90AjKAU7CQ6Gw+GI-qojFsLEF1DoOjLgFrzcPxPE0tBlfezY4DNBuRNoyzKspQ9IMuuVwANQwAAjBcnbbpA7isC6Qjgmse6nBAFxAA)

Comment: I need typescript not javascript

Comment: you are correct but there is one problem, my array is not type of `string` it's` myObject` but when I change the code it gives me error that it can't be anything except `string` or `number`

Comment: This information is not specified in the question. What is the type of `myObject` @SpacemanSps

Comment: it's a class that contain data like in java set and get class, so all data that read will be assign to this class because the input data I get is Json and that works pretty good except here

Comment: Can you show the class responsible? Are set and get always present? I need a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help :)

Comment: @SpacemanSps Look at the provided answer. It has been updated to reflect the usage of any object.

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach of a list reducer using a function that return another function. That way you can always specify which key to use, in your case this key is 0.

```
interface PropObject {
  [index: string]: number;
}

const groupByCounter = (key : number) => (result : PropObject ,current : string []) => {

  result[current[key]] = result[current[key]] ? result[current[key]] + 1 : 1;
  return result;
};

const data : string [][] = [["Car","model","year","color","price"],
["Table","model","year","color","price"],
["Car","model","year","color","price"],
["Car","model","year","color","price"],
["Laptop","model","year","color","price"],
["Laptop","model","year","color","price"]];

const group = data.reduce(groupByCounter(0),{});
console.log(group);
```

[Link to typescript playground.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=20&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKAlgdgLgpgTgMwIYGMYAIAKcD2AHAeQCMArGFKdAb1HXQG1IATGADwC50BnKOSAcwC6nCAFcAtkXgBuUAF9QoFDgg90-XKLwAhAJ4BhHKOjx0AXnQAKANYxd6ERKlwAlOYB8VuDC6iANpSc2PjEZBToADQoonDe0A7cvAIMgm5mnjQgtOjevgH00bEw0PS2uoKC5jk+-lAFMXF1ZRXoAPzVeXWFjaV2LQDU6ACMCUOyIHTeUDEQHbXjcuNKKmpMSFBICTx8EPwp9JUW9PQARPpIcCcRJ+I4LH5XJ7owF4-KfjiX13h8aCeCEVApwAKkgiH4YI9bvdHs9Xtd3p9Hj8wH8AUCzvCbncYA9rnCvidEYSUWjASBTudCdDcbCXoTicjfpD0RSTgAZJB4KD4KE4vFPelvHAfEnM-7k06c7m8640gUE4WipmolmCJYgZSqSgaIx4KprDYAOm8TFEaEsuq0ekMxlgcEsAAYXBEqHIXOMtVwRTAjR9+JbNHgPUA)

[Check out the javascript version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54147945/2739274)

Comment: Some of this code is redundant (checking if the type is "undefined"). Undefined values are falsy by nature, so `result[key]` suffices. Also the `typeof` operator is redundant. If you want to explicitly checks if undefined, `result[key] == undefined` suffices.

Comment: @Urmzd I have updated the code

Comment: @DavidLemon could you please help me to fix this problem? this is the error I get `No overload matches this call.  Argument of type '(result: PropObject, current: string[]) => PropObject' is not assignable to parameter of type '(previousValue: allData, currentValue: allData, currentIndex: number, array: allData[]) => allData'.       Types of parameters 'result' and 'previousValue' are incompatible.         Type 'allData' is not assignable to type 'PropObject'.           Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'allData'.` my array is my object type `allData: myObject[][]`

Comment: This code is also very dangerous. Mutating objects directly is never recommended..

Answer (score 0):

Why not use lodash ?

u can get this with only 2 lines :

```
private groupByObjects() {
  //this read all data in array allData[] from service
  this.dataService.retrieveData().subscribe(allData => {
  const counts = _.countBy(allData, '[0]');
  const data = _.unionBy(allData, '[0]');
  console.log(counts, data);
});
```

do not forget to install and import lodash :

```
npm install -s lodash

import * as _ from 'lodash';
```

Comment: Why? This just makes your bundle size larger for no reason.

Comment: import { countBy, unionBy } from 'lodash';

Comment: Still, why. There's no reason to add an additional dependency for one use case...

Comment: I don't want to use a library for this but the library is javascript and I need typescript

Answer (score 0):

Given that you are already using rxjs, I would stay using that. I don't know if you'll think it's the best answer, and I didn't test it so you might have to debug, but I find this solution fun.

```
type Item = [string, string, string, string, string]; // you should make this tighter
type ItemCount = [string, number];

const source$: Observable<Item[]> = of([
  ["Car","model","year","color","price"],
  ["Table","model","year","color","price"],
  ["Car","model","year","color","price"],
  ["Car","model","year","color","price"],
  ["Laptop","model","year","color","price"],
  ["Laptop","model","year","color","price"]
]); // mock of this.dataService.retrieveData()

source$.pipe(
  mergeMap(res => from(res)), // emit each item one at a time
  groupBy((item: Item) => item[0]),
  mergeMap((item$: GroupedObservable<Item>) => item$.pipe( // item$ is an observable of items were each item's first element equals item$.key
    count(), // wait until complete, then emit count
    map<number, ItemCount>(c => [item$.key, c]) // turn count into tuple of [key, count]
  )),
  toArray(), // Wait until each item$ has been converted, then emit the final ItemCount[]
  map((itemCounts: ItemCount[]) => new Map<string, number>(itemCounts)) // you could do Object.fromEntries(itemCounts) instead. I like map objects
).subscribe(mapOfCountsPerKey => {
    // whatever you want to do
});
```

Comment: I need typescript not javascript

Comment: ... that *is* Typescript.

Comment: I converted my data to `Item[]` but there is nothing called `pipe` and it says this doesn't exist

Comment: But you are using rxjs, right? Did you skip the `of()`?

Comment: I didn't include the imports. You'll need lines at the top of your script with something like `import { of, from } from 'rxjs';` and `import { count, groupBy, mergeMap, map, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: it didn't work, it doesn't recognize `pipe`

Comment: D'oh! I corrected the source$ type from `Item[]` to `Observable<Item[]>`