# Javascript Array: return true, if array contains value n times successively

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to check an array, if it contains a value n times successively.

Example:
var array = [true, true, true, true, false]; ==> true, if true 4 times successively

var array = [true, false, false, true, true]; ==> false

Comment: show us your code of what you have tried.

Comment: So you need to do a loop of some sort

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve, but you will need some of those:
Array.some,
Array.filter,
Array.reduce

Comment: The answers in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements) can probably get you to the right direction.

Comment: Any value n times or a specific value n times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You need a counter and a quantifier, like [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some). Then check the value and increment on `true` or reset counter to zero.

```js
function check4(array) {
    var count = 0;
    return array.some(function (a) {
        return a ? ++count === 4 : count = 0;
    });
}

console.log(check4([true, true, true, true, false]));  // true
console.log(check4([true, true, true, false, true]));  // false
console.log(check4([true, false, false, true, true])); // false
```

Comment: He requires successive. Your code returns true for: check4([true, false, false, true, true, true])

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with reduce:

```
const spree = array.reduce((acum, el) => el === val ? acum + 1 : 0, 0);
if (spree > 4) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this - this function accepts an array, the number of times you're checking for, and the value you're testing.

```
     function check (arr, number,val) {
  result=false;
    counter=1;
    for (i=1; i<arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i]===arr[i-1]) {counter++;} else {counter=1;}
        console.log(counter);
        if (counter>=number) {result=true;}
    }
    return result;
};
```

Of course, there are more elegant ways (you can break the moment you find a false), and the counters can be handled more elegantly.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest one:

```js
var has4True = function(arr){ 
    return /(true){4}/.test(arr.join('')); 
};

console.log(has4True([false, true, true, true, true, false]));
console.log(has4True([true, false, false, true, true]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var testArray = [true, true, true, true, false];
var searchVal = true;
var findTarget = 4;
var findAmount = 0;

for (var i=0; i<testArray.length; i++)
{
    if (testArray[i] == searchVal)
    {
        findAmount++;
    }
}

var findSuccess = (findAmount == findTarget);
```

testArray can contain any value to test against.

searchVal is the value to test against.

findTarget is how many times it needs to be found.

findSuccess will contain a true or false based on whether the condition has been met.