# Storing Data in Array and filter by Time and summarize and get Count

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the following ? I have an Array which stores the IP address and a DateTime , the datetime format is flexible so i could use timestamp or actual datetime whatever is better. What i want to be able to do is query the Array and check if a certain IP has been added lets say 5 times in the last minute.
The reason behind this is, that i want to catch users who try to scan my express servers for open holes and add them automatically to my blacklist. Currently i add all 404 not found requests to the array. When doing so i want to check how many records are in array for the timeframe.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements

Answer (score 0):

Yep. You can filter only the entries from the last minute with `Array.filter`, then count the number of each IP with `Array.reduce`, and finally filter only the IPs that appear more than 5 times with another `Array.filter`:

```
const counts = data
  .filter(entry => (Date.now() - entry.dateTime) < 60)
  .reduce((result, entry) => {
      result[entry.IP] = (result[entry.IP] || 0) + 1;
      return result;
    }, {});
const flagged = Object.keys(counts)
  .filter(IP => counts[IP] >= 5);
```

Then `flagged` will have a list of the IPs which are in the `data` array more than 5 times in the last minute.