# Javascript - Filter an array with objects className

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, count

I have a parent class called **Tree** and i build objects from children contructor **Fruit_obj** and **Book_obj** stored in Tree.m_objects. This is my array :

```
Tree.m_objects = [{Fruit_obj}, {Fruit_obj}, {Fruit_obj}, {Book_obj}, {Book_obj}];
```

When i console.log(Tree.m_objects) in DevTools, it shows :

```
► O : Fruit_obj {Some members}
► 1 : Fruit_obj {Some members}
► 2 : Fruit_obj {Some members}
► 3 : Book_obj {Some members}
► 4 : Book_obj {Some members}
```

What i want to do, is to filter my array to count how many occurrence of `Fruit_obj` i have in my array. But i only want to filter them by their **className** (here, `Fruit_obj`).

[Edit: Thanks to Adiga, i found that i need to use `instanceOf` to find my class name]

```
const fruits = array.filter(o => o instanceof Fruit_obj);
return fruits.length;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: @Rajesh I wouldn't have marked it if it didn't show up within 10 seconds of searching from within the dupe vote screen itself. I just did `array count [javascript]` and it was the second item. If I didn't get a result (at least one that didn't require scrolling), I'd have left it, honestly.

Comment: I'm completely new to Javascript buddys... @Rajesh it's not kind. And if i post here, it's because i don't know what to search for.

Comment: @KubNetwork I understand that. If you were expert, you wont post question in the first place. But the point is, you should put some effort. Even if you search your title, you will get some help. Then its a matter of connecting the dots. And effort does not mean just code, you can even share your search queries/ any reference link you found but didn't help

Comment: @KubNetwork Please refer to my last comment under *adiga*'s comment. That should be all you needed to solve on your own. Also, a user with your rep should know importance of effort. We are here to help and not do others' work. Hope to see you again but with me helping!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming `Fruit_obj` is the name of class or constrcutor function. You could use [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to filter the array:

```
const fruits = array.filter(o => o instanceof Fruit_obj)
```

This returns all the objects of type `Fruit_obj`. You can get the count using `fruits.length`

Comment: @Rajesh this is not that trivial or obvious  to google tbh. `Fruit_obj` is not a property

Comment: @adiga Thans adiga, it's exactly what i was looking for :)

Comment: True. The problem has 2 parts. 1. How to filter objects and count them. 2. How to check if object is of a specific constructor. My POV is, if OP shares some effort, google search query, reference links they followed, code, we know their level and draft answer in that way. Just solving the problem is wrong as that does not solve the real problem

Comment: @Rajesh See, your explanation is really helpfull Rajesh. I do not know that i needed to focus on "How to check if object is of a specific constructor". I was in lack of the correct term to answer my question AND to trying to find solution before posting. So thank you, and please be a little more kind with newby... Have a good day

Answer (score 2):

With the help of `filter()` and `hasOwnProperty()` you can get the count

```js
const array = [{'Fruit_obj': 1}, {'name': 1}, {'Fruit_obj': 1}, {'name': 1}, {'Fruit_obj': 1}];
const length = array.filter(obj => obj.hasOwnProperty('Fruit_obj')).length
console.log(length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do something like this to get the number of objects with the key `Fruit_obj`

```
array.filter(obj => obj['Fruit_obj']).length
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.hasOwnProperty()` to search for the property `Fruit_obj` in the object

Comment: `.hasOwnProperty` is used to filter via a property value of my object. What i needed, is to filter my array with the className. I'll use `instanceof`