# Javascript - Convert one Array into two after Group-by in

Tags: javascript, arrays, group-by

I have array like below

```
myArray = ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "zoom"]
```

I want output like this

```
nameArray = ["foo", "bar", "zoom"]
```

and

```
qtyArray = [2, 4, 1]
```

I will be using Plotly out of resulting two arrays to draw bar plot.

TIA

Comment: This answer may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/35101824/7692859

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and get the keys and values.

```js
var array = ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "zoom"],
    map = array.reduce((m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || 0) + 1), new Map),
    values = [...map.keys()],
    counts = [...map.values()];

console.log(...values);
console.log(...counts);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use reduce function. Inside the callback check if the accumulator object have a key by name of foo or bar or zoom. If it is there then increase the count by 1 else create a key by that name and put 1 as value. Then you can use `Object.keys` to create an array of keys which will be `foo,bar & zoom` & `Object.values` to get an array of the counts

```js
let myArray = ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "zoom"];

let newData = myArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  if (acc[curr]) {
    acc[curr] += 1;
  } else {
    acc[curr] = 1;

  }
  return acc;
}, {});

let nameArray = Object.keys(newData);
let qtyArray = Object.values(newData);
console.log(nameArray, qtyArray)
```

Comment: FYI: If the array has *integer-like* items, the order of `Object.keys()` will change.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myArray = ["foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "bar", "bar", "zoom"]; 
var arr = {}
myArray.map(function(x){
  if(typeof(arr[x])=="undefined") {arr[x] =0;}
  arr[x]++;
})

var arr1 = Object.keys(arr);
arr2 = arr1.map(x=>arr[x])


/* arr1
foo,bar,zoom
*/

/* arr2
2,4,1
*/
```