# Count no. of elements in an array inside setInterval : Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing elements .

What I want is to count the no. of elements every time when the Set Interval function loads in javascript.

Something like a counter but when I am using the count function it's displaying an error :

> Uncaught TypeError: x.count is not a function

I just want to count the no. of values when setinterval function occurs every time starting from 0 .

Here is the Code :

```js
var countArray = ["2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.232000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.233000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.234000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.235000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.236000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.237000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.238000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.239000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.240000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.241000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.242000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.243000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.244000"];

console.log(countArray.length);


var j = 0;

function countval() {
  return countArray[j++];
}

setInterval(function() {
  var counter = 0;
  x = countval();
  console.log("X value: ", x);
  counter = x.count();
  console.log("Count: ", counter);
}, 1000);
```

for example: `console.log("Count: ", counter);` should print:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

after each second.

**Update:**
My queston is of string format. how so I want to count the no. of string elements occurence in an array.

Comment: `countArray` is an array of strings, so `x` is a string, and strings have no `count` method

Comment: I want to count the no. of elements occurence in an array. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: not exactly. my array elements are of `String ` type @AZ_

Comment: what difference does that make? did you try going through all the solutions?

Comment: Instead of x.count() you can use x.length

Comment: x.length gives string length. @ArijitJana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite simple. You're assigning `x = countVal();` and `countVal()` returns a string value, so basically you're doing this: `"2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000".count();` which is an incorrect statement. So, Firstly remove this line from your code. Other than that I'm having difficulty understanding what you're trying to do, from reading you're question I assumed you want something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(j < countArray.length){
        x = countval(); 
        console.log("X value: ", x);
        console.log("Count: ", j);
    }
}, 1000);
```

And if you want to show the length of each element of the array just edit your `.count()` to `.length`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is solved with this code

```js
var countArray = ["2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.232000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.233000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.234000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.235000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.236000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.237000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.238000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.239000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.240000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.241000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.242000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.243000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.244000"];

console.log(countArray.length);


var j = 0;

function countval() {
  return countArray[j++];
}

setInterval(function() {
if(j <= countArray.length){
  var counter = 0;
  console.log("Count: ", j);
  console.log("X value: ", countval());
}
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script will be like this:

```
  var countArray = ["2020-14-03 11:14:48.225000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.226000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.227000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.228000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.229000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.230000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.231000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.232000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.233000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.234000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.235000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.236000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.237000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.238000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.239000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.240000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.241000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.242000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.243000","2020-14-03 11:14:48.244000"];

  console.log(countArray.length) ;


var j = 0;
  function countval() 
  {
   return countArray[j++];
  }

setInterval(function(){
  var counter = 0;
  x= countval();
  console.log("X value: ", x);
  counter=countArray.indexOf(x);
console.log("Count: ", counter);
  }, 1000);
```