# mach beginning javascript with Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Good afternoon, I am trying to make a method that tells me the number of elements an Array has that starts with "RT:"

For this I have developed the following code:

```
public getRowsRTs(idProyecto){

    this.twitterService.getTargets().subscribe((data) => {

        this.Twitter = data;

    });
   let countRT = this.Twitter.filter( tweet => tweet.message.startsWith("RT:")).length;

   return countRT;
    }
}
```

Here, data returns all the Documents that Mongo extracts, and puts them in the Twitter Array that I have defined at the beginning of the component. Within this Array each element has different attributes, such as _id, message, date ... I want you to tell me how many of those documents, the message value, begins with RT: and to return it to me, this code , it does not give me any problem, but it does not give me absolutely nothing, I do not know if someone could help me.

Comment: Is your property called `Array`? Can you give it a different name? Maybe `array`. And access the message with `array[i].message`.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] showing how you are defining `Array` and what kind of content it has in it.

Comment: Answered quickly so I didn't think about it but there are a ton of dupes on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

Comment: Of course what you refer to as your "test"  doesn't return anything, because `JSON.stringify` is going to return [ or { in the first position.  It is impossible to answer your question without knowing the input, and it's probably a duplicate as well.

Comment: The Array is an object that has an attribute that is message.

Answer (score 0):

If the array is filled with strings, this should work:

```
let regixForRTStart = /^RT:/;
    startArray = ['RT:1', 'RT:2', 'Other', 'Stuff'],
    count = startArray.filter(item => regixForRTStart.test(item))

// length
console.log(count.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `filter` and `startsWith` methods.

```js
const arr = [
  { message: "abc" },
  { message: "RT:" },
  { message: "RT: 2" },
  { message: "test" }
];

const count = arr.filter(({ message }) => message.startsWith("RT:")).length;

console.log(count);
```