# JavaScript: Print character with number of uninterrupted occurrences for each sequence of characters

Tags: javascript, arrays, find-occurrences

This is not a duplicate of [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)
There are differences.

I've got an array with chars:

```
const data = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'a'];
```

I need to count each sequence of characters and print character with number of uninterrupted occurrences like this (each line should log after program finds uninterrupted occurrences:

```
a: 2
b: 1
x: 3
a: 1
```

I thought to use 'while' but I'm stuck a little bit on this logic.

```
const countSeq = (arr) => {

  while (arr.length > 0) {

    // logic there

    console.log(/*char: count number*/);

    if (arr.length === 0) break;

  }

}
```

Sorry for bothering, I'm just learning. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @a1tern4tive that was not my intent - i genuinely want to help if you have something specific about where you get stuck. you'll learn best if you push yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'a'];

const result = data.reduce((acc, val) => {
    const prevSeq = acc[acc.length - 1];

    if (!prevSeq || prevSeq.key !== val) {
        acc.push({ key: val, count: 1 });
    } else {
        prevSeq.count++;
    }

    return acc;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The output of your answer does not match the expected output

Comment: @Andreas He can ask a question in a comment. His answer is not valid JS, on this he may also ask a question.

Comment: @Andreas *are better* I'm not saying that my answer is good, but I don’t see the answers anymore at all, if you open the topic deeper, I’ll delete my answer