# Counting ocurrencies / frequency of given value in a array inside object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, filter

im new to javascript and lets say i have an array of objects (books) like this:

```
let books = [{"pubDate":"2014", "authors":["John","Bob","Tom"], "name":"Book 1"}, {"pubDate":"2020", "authors":["Bob","Greg"], "name":"Book 2"}]
let authorsFrequency = getFrequency(books);
console.log(authorsFrequency) // expected result {"Bob":2,"Tom":1,"Greg":1,"John":1}
```

How could i properly build this getFrequency function? I've seen some similar questions like this one: [Counting the occurrences / frequency of array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5667888/counting-the-occurrences-frequency-of-array-elements)

But not one as deep as my example.

Results order doesn't matter, infact the fastest the better since i need to loop through 30.000 books.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Flatten the authors - `books.flatMap(o => o.authors)` and then use the solutions in the answers you've added to count the items.

Comment: @OriDrori it works! tyvm! How do i mark your answer as the the solution?

Comment: You're welcome :) However, this is not a solution, just a comment. I'm closing your question as a duplicate because the answer exists in the link you've added.